# Delete all records from all tables of database

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Is there any way to delete all records from all tables of a database yet keeping all the constraints.

I used a script available on net but it fails where foreign keys are defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you truncate all tables in a database using TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155246/how-do-you-truncate-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql)

Comment: This answer will work with FK constraints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155246/how-do-you-truncate-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql/156813#156813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_EmplyAllTable
AS
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL’
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘DELETE FROM ?’
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable ‘ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL’
GO
```