# unit testing a database query via nhibernate

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, nhibernate

I need to create a unit test for a method which loads data from the database. I was researching a bit into unit testing and databases, and most articles tell you that you should mock the database.  However, this method basically loads objects from a database, and performs some restrictions via SQL.

Therefore, what I want to test is that the actual database query is working successful, hence I don't think one can mock the database.

I am using NHibernate as my ORM, and the query is being built using `QueryOver`.  I find it extremely problematic to unit-test databases, due to the database being in an inconsistent state.  Any ideas / methods how one would go about doing such a test?

This is the particular method I would like to unit-test:

```
public IEnumerable<IArticlePanel> LoadPanelsApplicableToArticle(ArticleModule.IArticle article, Enums.ARTICLE_PANEL_LOCATION location)
   {
       CS.General_v3.Util.ContractsUtil.RequiresNotNullable(article, "Article must not be null");

       var articleList = Modules.Factories.ArticleFactory.GetAllParentsForAnArticle(article).ToList();
       articleList.Add(article);

       var q = GetQuery();
       q = q.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Article).IsInG(articleList.ConvertAll<long>(x => ((IBaseDbObject)x).ID));
       q = q.Where(x => x.Location == location);
       return FindAll(q);
 }
```

Comment: switch to a sqlite database for testing.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, when I've needed to unit test a database, I have usually used [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). You basically set up the SQLite database in memory, then configure your NHibernate (dependency injection, or however you want to do it) to connect to SQLite instead of your normal database. Almost all queries should be able to run correctly.

If you need strong DateTime support, SQLite will probably let you down (see Ayende's post about that [here](http://ayende.com/blog/2144/unit-testing-database-embedded-vs-in-memory)). In that case, you can use any of the embedded databases. I would recommend setting up a RAMDisk and place the embedded database on that disk, so it still runs in-memory.

Comment: The problem with such an approach is that there are some settings, and other values that must be in the database as certain initialisation code, etc depend on them.  Thus, I would need to recreate an SQLite from scratch, fill these settings etc.  I've tried going down this route but from time to time it came up quite impossible to maintain.

Comment: If you are in a case where unit testing the database itself is actually critical, then investing a little bit of extra time to write the SQLite database creation and customization code is usually not a huge deal. I have never had a case where it took more than a day to write everything needed to initialize the database, then it's done for all future unit tests. If it's not worth that much time, it's probably not worth worrying about unit tests for the data layer at all.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have used real databases to do my integration tests.  I feel that this is the closest to real production scenarios as possible.  Our development team is not currently generating the database from the nhibernate mappings so there were some inconsistencies between the mappings and the database (things like database defaults etc).  If you are generating the schema from nhibernate SQLLite may be the right path for you.  But if you aren't I personally feel that it's better to write these tests against the real database.

My integration tests will insert the necessary data for the tests and delete the data after the test.  The only pitfall to this method is that you have to make sure you delete all the data after your test is over otherwise it could affect other tests.  I've found this to be a viable solution for our company though and it's been extremely helpful.  We have a dedicated database only used for unit testing.

Below is an example of one of my tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_NHibernate_Query()
{
    //Create the data in the database necessary to test my nhibernate query
    CreateDataForUnitTest();

    IInventoryRepository target = new InventoryRepository(nhibernateSession);

    IList<InventoryView> inventoryRecords = target.GetContainerInventory(productId);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, inventoryRecords.Count);
}

[TestCleanup]
public void CleanUp()
{
    DeleteAll<Order>();
    DeleteAll<Company>();
}

public void DeleteAll<T>() where T : Entity
{
    NHibernate.ISession session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

    using (NHibernate.ITransaction tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        IList<T> items = session.CreateCriteria<T>()
            .List<T>();

        foreach (T p in items)
        {
            session.Delete(p);
        }

        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how I work at the moment.  However, sometimes due to dependencies it is not so easy to clean up after and bring the database back to a consistent state.  I wanted more to see if whether there are options which I am not aware of at the moment, however it seems that this is the best way to go for my case.

Comment: If you are using mssql there may be an easy way to get the database back in a consistent state if that consistent state means empty.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155246/how-do-you-truncate-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql  I may actually look into doing this instead.

Answer (score 0):

We use IRepository from NCommon. Then we use InMemoryRepository for unit testing. Very slick, fast, and easy to use.