# Intermittent crash in API Manager Analytics Dashboard

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I’m running API Manager 3.0 along with API Manager Analytics. My Analytics cluster is a single-node deployment. Using only a few dashboard widgets to monitor some APIs.

I’m facing intermittent outage of the analytics dashboard and dashboard homepage goes blank sometimes. What could be the possible reason for the same?

I don't see any errors in the log.

Comment: There can be many reasons for this behaviour. Did you start the Analytics profile after starting the API Manager? Also, what is the hardware configuration of the Analytics node? How many transactions being processed by the Gateway runtime. If you can share some of the above information, it would be beneficial to identify the cause.

Comment: I have a single-node deployment for testing purposes. I'm running both API Manager and Analytics in the same VM. Started API Manager runtime before starting the Analytics runtime. This has been working well for some time. However, both API Manager and Analytics connect to the same SQL Server database instance. Recently we faced **tempdb** issues in the SQL server. But it was not related to WSO2 products.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this has something to with your backend MSSSQL database. Microsoft SQL has the common issue of unrealistic growth of **temp** db specially when the same instance being used for multiplee applications.

You can try below options:

1. Try truncating MSSQL databases using below guides [1]
   [How do you truncate all tables in a database using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155246/how-do-you-truncate-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql)
2. Alternatively try to purge Analytics data as well and free some up space by removing historical data [2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/analytics/purging-analytics-data/