# How can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, constraints

Are disabling and enabling foreign key constraints supported in SQL Server? Or is my only option to **`drop`** and then **re-`create`** the constraints?

Comment: For folks asking "why" I would want to do this: It is for a test environment where I want to be able to remove and load test data from multiple tables without needing to maintain and specify the order of how the data is loaded. Data integrity is not that important for this scenario.

Comment: Note - if you want to TRUNCATE the table, you'll need to actually drop the constraints.

Comment: @OutstandingBill Apparently, [this works for TRUNCATE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8074510/712526).

Comment: It seems odd that anybody would question it In a _production_ environment. A very common use case is for bulk inserts. If you have a self-referential table, it's sometimes extremely difficult to sort a bulk insert so that the parent row is always inserted before the child, so you disable the constraint, bulk insert, enable the constraint.

Comment: Moreover, you may have a deliberately denormalized schema with redundant columns in a few places (whether for performance or other reasons).  These can then be tied together with FKs so that the redundancy doesn't allow errors to creep in.  But to update one of these redundantly stored values (hopefully a rare occurrence) you need to temporarily disable the FKs.

Answer (score 1242, accepted):

If you want to disable all constraints in the database just run this code:

```
-- disable all constraints
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

To switch them back on, run: (the print is optional of course and it is just listing the tables)

```
-- enable all constraints
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?'", @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

I find it useful when populating data from one database to another. It is much better approach than dropping constraints. As you mentioned it comes handy when dropping all the data in the database and repopulating it (say in test environment).

If you are deleting all the data you may find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155246/how-do-you-truncate-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql#156813) to be helpful.

Also sometimes it is handy to disable all triggers as well, you can see the complete solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123558/sql-server-2005-t-sql-to-temporarily-disable-a-trigger#123966).

Comment: I had to make a mass migration because I created a new Sql Server database to restructure, and this code was very helpful to make my migration code work

Comment: `"ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"`
Should there be only one "CHECK" there?

Comment: @CrazyPyro - no you need both

Comment: @CrazyPyro: both are indeed needed, reason for that is because the first CHECK belongs with the WITH and the second CHECK with the CONSTRAINT (it's the type of constraint). The first CHECK ensures your data gets checked for consistency when activating the constraint. If you don't want that, you could write WITH NOCHECK. Can be useful in certain test situations when you don't care about the actual data, as long as there is some so that your queries have something to play with.

Comment: Is it bad that I get this result on the second command?  "The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint ..."

Comment: It's worth noting that even with constraints disabled, TRUNCATE TABLE won't work. For that, you will need to drop the constraints. Otherwise, use DELETE FROM, but take into consideration the difference: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1080/deleting-data-in-sql-server-with-truncate-vs-delete-commands/

Comment: @ James that's a good point - you can check [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155246/how-do-you-truncate-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql#156813) which I also reference here

Comment: Just a note for everyone that sp_msforeachtable is not available on Azure SQL

Comment: Also note NOCHECK CONSTRAINT is not available in any SQL Server Compact Editions (CE), as of posting this comment.

Comment: Can I apply this to all tables because I dont want to run this command 20 times

Comment: the CHECK CHECK fails for me on SQL Server 2008R2, with `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'check'.`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my SQL server 2008 R2. The contraints are still there... :(

Comment: Just a note that TRUNCATE TABLE myTable still checks constraints, have to do DELETE FROM myTable. Also re-enabling constraints doesn't work if a required row to satisfy constraint doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: If you get `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CHECK'.`, as per comment by @ekkis, make sure you don't miss out the `WITH` keyword like I did.

Comment: Thank you james for the note about this not working with TRUNCATE TABLE it was buried under the more comments and I was frustrated about this until I saw I could just DELETE FROM the table instead.

Comment: @ScottBeeson this means when you've readded the constraint, you've got mismatched foreign/primary keys inserted into your table, or you are not allowing nulls and there are nulls where you should have key values. It sounds like you've inserted data (with relationship that needs preserving) into your table without maintaining the relationship.

Comment: Getting error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all' at line 1`

Comment: @Valentino Vranken, actually the second CHECK is not used here to indicate the type of constraint. The meaning of it here is that It gives the instruction to enable the constraint. Compare when you disable, in which case you write NOCHECK.

Comment: this doesn't work, I get an error when trying to change column datatype after running the first part: "The object 'DF__table_blahblah' is dependent on column 'mycolname'."

Comment: Sometimes this undocumented stored procedure is not there in the database. This gives 0 records: `SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE name like 'sp_MSforeach%';`, so then an attempt at using it e.g. `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable SELECT 1 AS FOO` gives error message `Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 15
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_MSforeachtable'.`

Comment: This is very dangerous! This will enable constraints that had been previously disabled. `select * from sys.foreign_keys where is_disabled = 1` tells you if you have this scenario.

Answer (score 451):

(Copied from from http://www.sqljunkies.com/WebLog/roman/archive/2005/01/30/7037.aspx,
[which is now archived in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20060901043621/http://www.sqljunkies.com/WebLog/roman/archive/2005/01/30/7037.aspx))

> Foreign key constraints and check constraint are very useful for enforcing data integrity and business rules. There are certain scenarios though where it is useful to temporarily turn them off because their behavior is either not needed or could do more harm than good. I sometimes disable constraint checking on tables during data loads from external sources or when I need to script a table drop/recreate with reloading the data back into the table. I usually do it in scenarios where I don't want a time consuming process to fail because one or a few of many million rows have bad data in it. But I always turn the constraints back on once the process is finished and also in some cases I run data integrity checks on the imported data.

> If you disable a foreign key constraint, you will be able to insert a value that does not exist in the parent table. If you disable a check constraint, you will be able to put a value in a column as if the check constraint was not there. Here are a few examples of disabling and enabling table constraints:

> ```
>    -- Disable all table constraints
>    ALTER TABLE MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
>
>    -- Enable all table constraints
>    ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
>     
>    -- Disable single constraint
>    
>    ALTER TABLE MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT MyConstraint
>    
>    -- Enable single constraint
>    ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT MyConstraint
> ```

Comment: a good find, but note that you still cannot truncate the table without removing the foreign key constraints

Comment: and you will also need to be aware that when you turn the constraints back on and do a data integrity check, your data may fail and fixng an issue like that can be a nightmare if the failing data is at the end of a long string of linked constraints.

Comment: my sql server 2008 asks for check check instead of check and check nocheck

Comment: You also need a second check when turning the constraints back on.  Otherwise, as-is, your code will only check the constraint once, not turn it on.

Comment: yes, "with check check" needed for 2012.  Edit was rejected? [MS Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098554/sql-server-how-to-make-server-check-all-its-check-constraints/1098629#1098629)

Comment: I'm not able to get this to work inside an Entity Framework code first migration, using the Sql() statement to temporarily disable FKs before dropping a PK in order to convert it to a non-clustered index. I had to drop and recreate the FKs. Any ideas?

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe - That is correct, but you can still `delete from MyTable`

Comment: The statements used here to re-enable the constraints are missing the WITH CHECK clauses. This is a pretty major flaw. See my answer for details - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35427150/81595.

Answer (score 56):

To disable the constraint you have `ALTER` the table using [NOCHECK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-check-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements)

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [ALL|CONSTRAINT_NAME]
```

To enable you to have to use double [CHECK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints):

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE_NAME] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [ALL|CONSTRAINT_NAME]
```

- Pay attention to the double **CHECK CHECK** when enabling.
- ALL means for all constraints in the table.

Once completed, if you need to check the status, use this script to list the constraint status. Will be very helpfull:

```
    SELECT (CASE 
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(CONSTID, 'CNSTISDISABLED') = 0 THEN 'ENABLED'
        ELSE 'DISABLED'
        END) AS STATUS,
        OBJECT_NAME(CONSTID) AS CONSTRAINT_NAME,
        OBJECT_NAME(FKEYID) AS TABLE_NAME,
        COL_NAME(FKEYID, FKEY) AS COLUMN_NAME,
        OBJECT_NAME(RKEYID) AS REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
        COL_NAME(RKEYID, RKEY) AS REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
   FROM SYSFOREIGNKEYS
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, KEYNO
```

Comment: Not ***view*** for _Primary keys_ ? For _foreign keys_ **SYSFOREIGNKEYS** _System View_ `sys.sysforeignkeys` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177604.aspx

Comment: if you are trying to disable primary key for insert, I would recomend using (SET IDENTITY_INSERT) if you want just check for primary key, you can try sys.key_constraints with sys.indexes.is_primary_key

Answer (score 34):

Your best option is to DROP and CREATE foreign key constraints.

I didn't find examples in this post that would work for me "as-is", one would not work if foreign keys reference different schemas, the other would not work if foreign key references multiple columns. This script considers both, multiple schemas and multiple columns per foreign key.

Here is the script that generates "ADD CONSTRAINT" statements, for multiple columns it will separate them by comma (**be sure to save this output before executing DROP statements**):

```
PRINT N'-- CREATE FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS --';

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT '
PRINT N''Creating '+ const.const_name +'...''
GO
ALTER TABLE ' + const.parent_obj + '
    ADD CONSTRAINT ' + const.const_name + ' FOREIGN KEY (
            ' + const.parent_col_csv + '
            ) REFERENCES ' + const.ref_obj + '(' + const.ref_col_csv + ')
GO'
FROM (
    SELECT QUOTENAME(fk.NAME) AS [const_name]
        ,QUOTENAME(schParent.NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_name(fkc.parent_object_id)) AS [parent_obj]
        ,STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(COL_NAME(fcP.parent_object_id, fcp.parent_column_id))
                FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fcP
                WHERE fcp.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
                FOR XML path('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS [parent_col_csv]
        ,QUOTENAME(schRef.NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id)) AS [ref_obj]
        ,STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(COL_NAME(fcR.referenced_object_id, fcR.referenced_column_id))
                FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fcR
                WHERE fcR.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
                FOR XML path('')
                ), 1, 1, '') AS [ref_col_csv]
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys AS fk ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS oParent ON oParent.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS schParent ON schParent.schema_id = oParent.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS oRef ON oRef.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS schRef ON schRef.schema_id = oRef.schema_id
    GROUP BY fkc.parent_object_id
        ,fkc.referenced_object_id
        ,fk.NAME
        ,fk.object_id
        ,schParent.NAME
        ,schRef.NAME
    ) AS const
ORDER BY const.const_name
```

Here is the script that generates "DROP CONSTRAINT" statements:

```
PRINT N'-- DROP FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS --';

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT '
PRINT N''Dropping ' + fk.NAME + '...''
GO
ALTER TABLE [' + sch.NAME + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) + ']' + ' DROP  CONSTRAINT ' + '[' + fk.NAME + ']
GO'
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS sch ON sch.schema_id = fk.schema_id
ORDER BY fk.NAME
```

Comment: Can u explain why it's better than disabling and re-enabling constraints?

Comment: Nice script. For a similar but alternative approach, see:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/

Comment: @MahmoodDehghan Old comment, but there are situations where disabling a constraint isn't enough. `The target table '???' of the INSERT statement cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship when the FROM clause contains a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE or MERGE statement.` Hit this today.

Comment: @MahmoodDehghan In my situation; Still I can't drop PK because of FK even I disabled them. I have to drop & create

Answer (score 14):

The SQL-92 standard allows for a constaint to be declared as DEFERRABLE so that it can be deferred (implicitly or explicitly) within the scope of a transaction. Sadly, SQL Server is still missing this SQL-92 functionality.

For me, changing a constraint to NOCHECK is akin to changing the database structure on the fly -- dropping constraints certainly is -- and something to be avoided (e.g. users require increased privileges).

Answer (score 13):

```
   --Drop and Recreate Foreign Key Constraints

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @table TABLE(
   RowId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
   ForeignKeyConstraintName NVARCHAR(200),
   ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema NVARCHAR(200),
   ForeignKeyConstraintTableName NVARCHAR(200),
   ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintName NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName NVARCHAR(200)    
)

INSERT INTO @table(ForeignKeyConstraintName, ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema, ForeignKeyConstraintTableName, ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName)
SELECT 
   U.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
   U.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
   U.TABLE_NAME, 
   U.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE U
      INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C
         ON U.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
   C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'

UPDATE @table SET
   PrimaryKeyConstraintName = UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM 
   @table T
      INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS R
         ON T.ForeignKeyConstraintName = R.CONSTRAINT_NAME

UPDATE @table SET
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema  = TABLE_SCHEMA,
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName  = TABLE_NAME
FROM @table T
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C
      ON T.PrimaryKeyConstraintName = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME

UPDATE @table SET
   PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName = COLUMN_NAME
FROM @table T
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE U
      ON T.PrimaryKeyConstraintName = U.CONSTRAINT_NAME

--SELECT * FROM @table

--DROP CONSTRAINT:
SELECT
   '
   ALTER TABLE [' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableName + '] 
   DROP CONSTRAINT ' + ForeignKeyConstraintName + '

   GO'
FROM
   @table

--ADD CONSTRAINT:
SELECT
   '
   ALTER TABLE [' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableName + '] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT ' + ForeignKeyConstraintName + ' FOREIGN KEY(' + ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName + ') REFERENCES [' + PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName + '](' + PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName + ')

   GO'
FROM
   @table

GO
```

---

I do agree with you, Hamlin. When you are transfer data using SSIS or when want to replicate data, it seems quite necessary to temporarily disable or drop foreign key constraints and then re-enable or recreate them. In these cases, referential integrity is not an issue, because it is already maintained in the source database. Therefore, you can rest assured regarding this matter.

Comment: This script is great for generating my "ALTER" commands, but how can I get these to execute/run in an SP?

Comment: I think this won't work if any of the foreign keys is multi-column

Comment: This also did not produce all characters for exceedingly long table/key names.

Answer (score 12):

**`WITH CHECK CHECK` is almost certainly required!**

This point was raised in some of the answers and comments but I feel that it is important enough to call it out again.

Re-enabling a constraint using the following command (no `WITH CHECK`) will have some [serious drawbacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable CHECK CONSTRAINT MyConstraint;
```

> WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK
>
> Specifies whether the data in the table is or is not validated against
>   a newly added or re-enabled FOREIGN KEY or CHECK constraint. If not
>   specified, WITH CHECK is assumed for new constraints, and WITH NOCHECK
>   is assumed for re-enabled constraints.
>
> If you do not want to verify new CHECK or FOREIGN KEY constraints
>   against existing data, use WITH NOCHECK. We do not recommend doing
>   this, except in rare cases. The new constraint will be evaluated in
>   all later data updates. Any constraint violations that are suppressed
>   by WITH NOCHECK when the constraint is added may cause future updates
>   to fail if they update rows with data that does not comply with the
>   constraint.
>
> The query optimizer does not consider constraints that are defined
>   WITH NOCHECK. Such constraints are ignored until they are re-enabled
>   by using ALTER TABLE table WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL.

**Note:** WITH NOCHECK is the default for re-enabling constraints. I have to wonder why...

1. No existing data in the table will be evaluated during the execution of this command - successful completion is no guarantee that the data in the table is valid according to the constraint.
2. During the next update of the invalid records, the constraint will be evaluated and will fail - resulting in errors that may be unrelated to the actual update that is made.
3. Application logic that relies on the constraint to ensure that data is valid may fail.
4. The query optimizer will not make use of any constraint that is enabled in this way.

The [sys.foreign_keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx) system view provides some visibility into the issue. Note that it has both an `is_disabled` and an `is_not_trusted` column. `is_disabled` indicates whether future data manipulation operations will be validated against the constraint. `is_not_trusted` indicates whether all of the data currently in the table has been validated against the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT MyConstraint;
```

Are your constraints to be trusted? Find out...

```
SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE is_not_trusted = 1;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @table TABLE(
   RowId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
   ForeignKeyConstraintName NVARCHAR(200),
   ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema NVARCHAR(200),
   ForeignKeyConstraintTableName NVARCHAR(200),
   ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintName NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName NVARCHAR(200),
   UpdateRule NVARCHAR(100),
   DeleteRule NVARCHAR(100)   
)

INSERT INTO @table(ForeignKeyConstraintName, ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema, ForeignKeyConstraintTableName, ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName)
SELECT 
   U.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
   U.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
   U.TABLE_NAME, 
   U.COLUMN_NAME
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE U
      INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C
         ON U.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
   C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'

UPDATE @table SET
   T.PrimaryKeyConstraintName = R.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME,
   T.UpdateRule = R.UPDATE_RULE,
   T.DeleteRule = R.DELETE_RULE
FROM 
   @table T
      INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS R
         ON T.ForeignKeyConstraintName = R.CONSTRAINT_NAME

UPDATE @table SET
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema  = TABLE_SCHEMA,
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName  = TABLE_NAME
FROM @table T
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C
      ON T.PrimaryKeyConstraintName = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME

UPDATE @table SET
   PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName = COLUMN_NAME
FROM @table T
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE U
      ON T.PrimaryKeyConstraintName = U.CONSTRAINT_NAME

--SELECT * FROM @table

SELECT '
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY'

--DROP CONSTRAINT:
SELECT
   '
 ALTER TABLE [' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableName + '] 
 DROP CONSTRAINT ' + ForeignKeyConstraintName + '
   '
FROM
   @table

SELECT '
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   RAISERROR(''Operation failed.'', 16, 1)
END CATCH

IF(@@TRANCOUNT != 0)
BEGIN
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
   RAISERROR(''Operation completed successfully.'', 10, 1)
END
'

--ADD CONSTRAINT:
SELECT '
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY'

SELECT
   '
   ALTER TABLE [' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableName + '] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT ' + ForeignKeyConstraintName + ' FOREIGN KEY(' + ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName + ') REFERENCES [' + PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName + '](' + PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName + ') ON UPDATE ' + UpdateRule + ' ON DELETE ' + DeleteRule + '
   '
FROM
   @table

SELECT '
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   RAISERROR(''Operation failed.'', 16, 1)
END CATCH

IF(@@TRANCOUNT != 0)
BEGIN
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
   RAISERROR(''Operation completed successfully.'', 10, 1)
END'

GO
```

Answer (score 9):

First post :)

For the OP, kristof's solution will work, unless there are issues with massive data and transaction log balloon issues on big deletes.  Also, even with tlog storage to spare, since deletes write to the tlog, the operation can take a VERY long time for tables with hundreds of millions of rows.

I use a series of cursors to truncate and reload large copies of one of our huge production databases frequently.  The solution engineered accounts for multiple schemas, multiple foreign key columns, and best of all can be sproc'd out for use in SSIS.

It involves creation of three staging tables (real tables) to house the DROP, CREATE, and CHECK FK scripts, creation and insertion of those scripts into the tables, and then looping over the tables and executing them.  The attached script is four parts: 1.) creation and storage of the scripts in the three staging (real) tables, 2.) execution of the drop FK scripts via a cursor one by one, 3.) Using sp_MSforeachtable to truncate all the tables in the database other than our three staging tables and 4.) execution of the create FK and check FK scripts at the end of your ETL SSIS package.

Run the script creation portion in an Execute SQL task in SSIS.  Run the "execute Drop FK Scripts" portion in a second Execute SQL task. Put the truncation script in a third Execute SQL task, then perform whatever other ETL processes you need to do prior to attaching the CREATE and CHECK scripts in a final Execute SQL task (or two if desired) at the end of your control flow.

Storage of the scripts in real tables has proven invaluable when the re-application of the foreign keys fails as you can select * from sync_CreateFK, copy/paste into your query window, run them one at a time, and fix the data issues once you find ones that failed/are still failing to re-apply.

Do not re-run the script again if it fails without making sure that you re-apply all of the foreign keys/checks prior to doing so, or you will most likely lose some creation and check fk scripting as our staging tables are dropped and recreated prior to the creation of the scripts to execute.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1)
/*
Author:         Denmach
DateCreated:    2014-04-23
Purpose:        Generates SQL statements to DROP, ADD, and CHECK existing constraints for a 
                database.  Stores scripts in tables on target database for execution.  Executes
                those stored scripts via independent cursors. 
DateModified:
ModifiedBy
Comments:       This will eliminate deletes and the T-log ballooning associated with it.
*/

DECLARE @schema_name SYSNAME; 
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME; 
DECLARE @constraint_name SYSNAME; 
DECLARE @constraint_object_id INT; 
DECLARE @referenced_object_name SYSNAME; 
DECLARE @is_disabled BIT; 
DECLARE @is_not_for_replication BIT; 
DECLARE @is_not_trusted BIT; 
DECLARE @delete_referential_action TINYINT; 
DECLARE @update_referential_action TINYINT; 
DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR(4000); 
DECLARE @tsql2 NVARCHAR(4000); 
DECLARE @fkCol SYSNAME; 
DECLARE @pkCol SYSNAME; 
DECLARE @col1 BIT; 
DECLARE @action CHAR(6);  
DECLARE @referenced_schema_name SYSNAME;



--------------------------------Generate scripts to drop all foreign keys in a database --------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sync_dropFK') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE sync_dropFK

CREATE TABLE sync_dropFK
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
    , Script NVARCHAR(4000)
    )

DECLARE FKcursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT 
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)
        , OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)
        , name
    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys WITH (NOLOCK)
    ORDER BY 
        1,2;

OPEN FKcursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO 
    @schema_name
    , @table_name
    , @constraint_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE '
                + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) 
                + '.' 
                + QUOTENAME(@table_name)
                + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' 
                + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name) 
                + ';';
    --PRINT @tsql;
    INSERT sync_dropFK  (
                        Script
                        )
                        VALUES (
                                @tsql
                                )   

    FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO 
    @schema_name
    , @table_name
    , @constraint_name
    ;

END;

CLOSE FKcursor;

DEALLOCATE FKcursor;


---------------Generate scripts to create all existing foreign keys in a database --------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sync_createFK') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE sync_createFK

CREATE TABLE sync_createFK
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
    , Script NVARCHAR(4000)
    )

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sync_createCHECK') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE sync_createCHECK

CREATE TABLE sync_createCHECK
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
    , Script NVARCHAR(4000)
    )   

DECLARE FKcursor CURSOR FOR

     SELECT 
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id)
        , OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)
        , name
        , OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id)
        , OBJECT_ID
        , is_disabled
        , is_not_for_replication
        , is_not_trusted
        , delete_referential_action
        , update_referential_action
        , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id)

    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys WITH (NOLOCK)

    ORDER BY 
        1,2;

OPEN FKcursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO 
    @schema_name
    , @table_name
    , @constraint_name
    , @referenced_object_name
    , @constraint_object_id
    , @is_disabled
    , @is_not_for_replication
    , @is_not_trusted
    , @delete_referential_action
    , @update_referential_action
    , @referenced_schema_name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

        BEGIN
            SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE '
                        + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) 
                        + '.' 
                        + QUOTENAME(@table_name)
                        +   CASE 
                                @is_not_trusted
                                WHEN 0 THEN ' WITH CHECK '
                                ELSE ' WITH NOCHECK '
                            END
                        + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' 
                        + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name)
                        + ' FOREIGN KEY (';

        SET @tsql2 = '';

        DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR FOR 

            SELECT 
                COL_NAME(fk.parent_object_id
                , fkc.parent_column_id)
                , COL_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id
                , fkc.referenced_column_id)

            FROM 
                sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc WITH (NOLOCK) ON fk.[object_id] = fkc.constraint_object_id

            WHERE 
                fkc.constraint_object_id = @constraint_object_id

            ORDER BY 
                fkc.constraint_column_id;

        OPEN ColumnCursor;

        SET @col1 = 1;

        FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @fkCol, @pkCol;

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

        BEGIN
            IF (@col1 = 1)
                SET @col1 = 0;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @tsql = @tsql + ',';
                SET @tsql2 = @tsql2 + ',';
            END;

            SET @tsql = @tsql + QUOTENAME(@fkCol);
            SET @tsql2 = @tsql2 + QUOTENAME(@pkCol);
            --PRINT '@tsql = ' + @tsql 
            --PRINT '@tsql2 = ' + @tsql2
            FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @fkCol, @pkCol;
            --PRINT 'FK Column ' + @fkCol
            --PRINT 'PK Column ' + @pkCol 
        END;

        CLOSE ColumnCursor;
        DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor;

        SET @tsql = @tsql + ' ) REFERENCES ' 
                    + QUOTENAME(@referenced_schema_name) 
                    + '.' 
                    + QUOTENAME(@referenced_object_name)
                    + ' (' 
                    + @tsql2 + ')';

        SET @tsql = @tsql
                    + ' ON UPDATE ' 
                    + 
                        CASE @update_referential_action
                            WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION '
                            WHEN 1 THEN 'CASCADE '
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'SET NULL '
                                ELSE 'SET DEFAULT '
                        END

                    + ' ON DELETE ' 
                    + 
                        CASE @delete_referential_action
                            WHEN 0 THEN 'NO ACTION '
                            WHEN 1 THEN 'CASCADE '
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'SET NULL '
                                ELSE 'SET DEFAULT '
                        END

                    + 
                    CASE @is_not_for_replication
                        WHEN 1 THEN ' NOT FOR REPLICATION '
                            ELSE ''
                    END
                    + ';';

        END;

    --  PRINT @tsql
        INSERT sync_createFK    
                        (
                        Script
                        )
                        VALUES (
                                @tsql
                                )

-------------------Generate CHECK CONSTRAINT scripts for a database ------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        BEGIN

        SET @tsql = 'ALTER TABLE '
                    + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) 
                    + '.' 
                    + QUOTENAME(@table_name)
                    + 
                        CASE @is_disabled
                            WHEN 0 THEN ' CHECK '
                                ELSE ' NOCHECK '
                        END
                    + 'CONSTRAINT ' 
                    + QUOTENAME(@constraint_name)
                    + ';';
        --PRINT @tsql;
        INSERT sync_createCHECK 
                        (
                        Script
                        )
                        VALUES (
                                @tsql
                                )   
        END;

    FETCH NEXT FROM FKcursor INTO 
    @schema_name
    , @table_name
    , @constraint_name
    , @referenced_object_name
    , @constraint_object_id
    , @is_disabled
    , @is_not_for_replication
    , @is_not_trusted
    , @delete_referential_action
    , @update_referential_action
    , @referenced_schema_name;

END;

CLOSE FKcursor;

DEALLOCATE FKcursor;

--SELECT * FROM sync_DropFK
--SELECT * FROM sync_CreateFK
--SELECT * FROM sync_CreateCHECK
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2.)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------execute Drop FK Scripts --------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @scriptD NVARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE DropFKCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Script 
    FROM sync_dropFK WITH (NOLOCK)

OPEN DropFKCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM DropFKCursor
INTO @scriptD

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--PRINT @scriptD
EXEC (@scriptD)
FETCH NEXT FROM DropFKCursor
INTO @scriptD
END
CLOSE DropFKCursor
DEALLOCATE DropFKCursor
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3.) 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------Truncate all tables in the database other than our staging tables --------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF OBJECT_ID(''?'') NOT IN 
(
ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''dbo.sync_createCHECK''),0),
ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''dbo.sync_createFK''),0),
ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''dbo.sync_dropFK''),0)
)
BEGIN TRY
 TRUNCATE TABLE ?
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 PRINT ''Truncation failed on''+ ? +''
END CATCH;' 
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------execute Create FK Scripts and CHECK CONSTRAINT Scripts---------------
----------------------------tack me at the end of the ETL in a SQL task-------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @scriptC NVARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE CreateFKCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Script 
    FROM sync_createFK WITH (NOLOCK)

OPEN CreateFKCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM CreateFKCursor
INTO @scriptC

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--PRINT @scriptC
EXEC (@scriptC)
FETCH NEXT FROM CreateFKCursor
INTO @scriptC
END
CLOSE CreateFKCursor
DEALLOCATE CreateFKCursor
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @scriptCh NVARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE CreateCHECKCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Script 
    FROM sync_createCHECK WITH (NOLOCK)

OPEN CreateCHECKCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM CreateCHECKCursor
INTO @scriptCh

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--PRINT @scriptCh
EXEC (@scriptCh)
FETCH NEXT FROM CreateCHECKCursor
INTO @scriptCh
END
CLOSE CreateCHECKCursor
DEALLOCATE CreateCHECKCursor
```

Answer (score 7):

Find the constraint

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('TABLE_NAME')
```

Execute the SQL generated by this SQL

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) +
    '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('TABLE_NAME')
```

Safeway.

**Note: Added solution for droping the constraint so that table can be dropped or modified without any constraint error.**

Answer (score 4):

Answer marked '905' looks good but does not work.

Following worked for me. Any Primary Key, Unique Key, or Default constraints **CAN NOT** be disabled. In fact, if 'sp_helpconstraint '' shows 'n/a' in status_enabled - Means it can **NOT** be enabled/disabled.

-- To generate script to DISABLE

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' + object_name(id) + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [' + object_name(constid) + ']'
from sys.sysconstraints 
where status & 0x4813 = 0x813 order by object_name(id)
```

-- To generate script to ENABLE

```
select 'ALTER TABLE ' + object_name(id) + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + object_name(constid) + ']'
from sys.sysconstraints 
where status & 0x4813 = 0x813 order by object_name(id)
```

Comment: Note: If you run the disable script, you cannot run the enable script after disabling all constraints. They are excluded by from the sys.sysconstraints entity once disabled. I.E Prep the script to re-enable constraints BEFORE disabling.

Answer (score 4):

You should actually be able to disable foreign key constraints the same way you temporarily disable other constraints:

```
Alter table MyTable nocheck constraint FK_ForeignKeyConstraintName
```

Just make sure you're disabling the constraint on the first table listed in the constraint name. For example, if my foreign key constraint was FK_LocationsEmployeesLocationIdEmployeeId, I would want to use the following:

```
Alter table Locations nocheck constraint FK_LocationsEmployeesLocationIdEmployeeId
```

even though violating this constraint will produce an error that doesn't necessarily state that table as the source of the conflict.

Answer (score 3):

Right click the table design and go to Relationships and choose the foreign key on the left-side pane and in the right-side pane, set Enforce foreign key constraint to 'Yes' (to enable foreign key constraints) or 'No' (to disable it).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a more useful version if you are interested. I lifted a bit of code from here a website where the link is no longer active. I modifyied it to allow for an array of tables into the stored procedure and it populates the drop, truncate, add statements before executing all of them. This gives you control to decide which tables need truncating.

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [util].[typ_objects_for_managing]    Script Date: 03/04/2016 16:42:55 ******/
CREATE TYPE [util].[typ_objects_for_managing] AS TABLE(
    [schema] [sysname] NOT NULL,
    [object] [sysname] NOT NULL
)
GO

create procedure [util].[truncate_table_with_constraints]
@objects_for_managing util.typ_objects_for_managing readonly

--@schema sysname
--,@table sysname

as 
--select
--    @table = 'TABLE',
--    @schema = 'SCHEMA'

declare @exec_table as table (ordinal int identity (1,1), statement nvarchar(4000), primary key (ordinal));

--print '/*Drop Foreign Key Statements for ['+@schema+'].['+@table+']*/'

insert into @exec_table (statement)
select
          'ALTER TABLE ['+SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)+'].['+ o.name+'] DROP CONSTRAINT ['+fk.name+']'
from sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join sys.objects o
          on fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
where 
exists ( 
select * from @objects_for_managing chk 
where 
chk.[schema] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)  
and 
chk.[object] = o.name
) 
;
          --o.name = @table and
          --SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)  = @schema

insert into @exec_table (statement) 
select
'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + src.[schema] + '.' + src.[object] 
from @objects_for_managing src
; 

--print '/*Create Foreign Key Statements for ['+@schema+'].['+@table+']*/'
insert into @exec_table (statement)
select 'ALTER TABLE ['+SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)+'].['+o.name+'] ADD CONSTRAINT ['+fk.name+'] FOREIGN KEY (['+c.name+']) 
REFERENCES ['+SCHEMA_NAME(refob.schema_id)+'].['+refob.name+'](['+refcol.name+'])'
from sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
inner join sys.foreign_keys fk
          on fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
inner join sys.objects o
          on fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
inner join sys.columns c
          on      fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id and
                   o.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.objects refob
          on fkc.referenced_object_id = refob.object_id
inner join sys.columns refcol
          on fkc.referenced_column_id = refcol.column_id and
                   fkc.referenced_object_id = refcol.object_id
where 
exists ( 
select * from @objects_for_managing chk 
where 
chk.[schema] = SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)  
and 
chk.[object] = o.name
) 
;

          --o.name = @table and
          --SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id)  = @schema



declare @looper int , @total_records int, @sql_exec nvarchar(4000)

select @looper = 1, @total_records = count(*) from @exec_table; 

while @looper <= @total_records 
begin

select @sql_exec = (select statement from @exec_table where ordinal =@looper)
exec sp_executesql @sql_exec 
print @sql_exec 
set @looper = @looper + 1
end
```

Comment: Dead link in your answer. Points to a blank article.

Comment: Hi, there may well be a deadlink but the whole code is specified in the piece. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Nothing wrong, but you probably should edit your answer and remove the dead link.

Answer (score 1):

One script to rule them all: this combines truncate and delete commands with sp_MSforeachtable so that you can avoid dropping and recreating constraints - just specify the tables that need to be deleted rather than truncated and for my purposes I have included an extra schema filter for good measure (tested in 2008r2)

```
declare @schema nvarchar(max) = 'and Schema_Id=Schema_id(''Value'')'
declare @deletiontables nvarchar(max) = '(''TableA'',''TableB'')'
declare @truncateclause nvarchar(max) = @schema + ' and o.Name not in ' +  + @deletiontables;
declare @deleteclause nvarchar(max) = @schema + ' and o.Name in ' + @deletiontables;        

exec sp_MSforeachtable 'alter table ? nocheck constraint all', @whereand=@schema
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'truncate table ?', @whereand=@truncateclause
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'delete from ?', @whereand=@deleteclause
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'alter table ? with check check constraint all', @whereand=@schema
```

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily disable constraints on your tables, do work, then rebuild them.

Here is an easy way to do it...

Disable all indexes, including the primary keys, which will disable all foreign keys, then re-enable just the primary keys so you can work with them...

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(max)=''
select @sql = @sql +
    'ALTER INDEX ALL ON [' + t.[name] + '] DISABLE;'+CHAR(13)
from  
    sys.tables t
where type='u'

select @sql = @sql +
    'ALTER INDEX ' + i.[name] + ' ON [' + t.[name] + '] REBUILD;'+CHAR(13)
from  
    sys.key_constraints i
join
    sys.tables t on i.parent_object_id=t.object_id
where
    i.type='PK'


exec dbo.sp_executesql @sql;
go
```

[Do something, like loading data]

Then re-enable and rebuild the indexes...

```
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(max)=''
select @sql = @sql +
    'ALTER INDEX ALL ON [' + t.[name] + '] REBUILD;'+CHAR(13)
from  
    sys.tables t
where type='u'

exec dbo.sp_executesql @sql;
go
```

Comment: This seemed promising, but `@sql` always gets truncated. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can easily turn of CONSTRAINT using :
ALTER TABLE TableName NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

After you finish the transaction do not forget to turn them on again using:
ALTER TABLE TableName CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL