# Sql 2005 data migration

Tags: sql-server, ssis, identity

I have the same database running on two different machines. The DB's make extensive use of Identity columns, and the tables have clashed pretty horribly. I now want to merge these two together before sorting out the undelying issue which I may do by

A) Using GUIDs (unweildy but works everywhere)
B) Assigning Identity ranges, kind of naff, but means you can still access records in order, knock up basic Sql and select records easily, and it identifies which machine originated the data.

My question is, what's the best way of re-keying (ie changing the primary keys) on one of the databases so the data no longer clashes. We're only looking at 6 tables total, but lots of rows ~2M in the 3 tables.

Update - is there any real sql code out there that does this, I know about Identity Insert etc. I've solved this issue in a number of in-elegant ways before, and I was looking for the elegant solution, preferable with a nice TSQL SP to do the donkey work - if that doesn't exist I'll code it up and place on wiki.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230006/renumber-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic way is to change all keys on the one of the databases by a fixed increment, say 10,000,000, and they will line up.  In order to do this, you will have to bring the applications down so the database is quiet and drop all FK references affected by this, recreating them when finished.  You will also have to reset the seed value on all affected identity columns to an appropriate value.

Some of the tables will be reference data, which will be more complicated to merge if it is not in sync.  You could possibly have issues with conflicting codes meaning the same thing on different instances or the same code having different meanings.  This may or may not be an issue with your application but if the instances have been run without having this coordinated between them you might want to check carefully for this.

Also, data like names and addresses are *very* likely to be out of sync if there wasn't a canonical source for these.  You may need to get these out, run a matching query and get the business to tidy up any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I would add another column to the table first, populate that with the new `Primary key`.

Then I'd use update statements to update the new `foreign key` fields in all related tables.

Then you can drop the old `Primary key` and old `foreign key` fields.