# Add a number to an existing number in an existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Old Tables joined on Key

Key Author
-------------------------
1   Author A
2   Author B
3   Author C
4   Author D
-------------------------

Key Book Title
-------------------------
1   Book Title by A
1   Book Title by A
4   Book Title by D
4   Book Title by D 
2   Book Title by B
-------------------------

New Tables joining on NewKey

NewKey  Key Author
-------------------------
1001    1   Author A
1002    2   Author B
1003    3   Author C
1004    4   Author D
-------------------------

NewKey  Key Book Title
-------------------------
1001    1   Book Title by A
1001    1   Book Title by A
1004    4   Book Title by D
1004    4   Book Title by D 
1002    2   Book Title by B
-------------------------

The purpose of creating the NewKey is when merging hundreds of databases together where the Key fields overlap, so this script would create a globally unique NewKey field prior to the merge. Each database has 11 tables with Key fields that overlap. So I need to complete this step for every table on the Key field.

Comment: Can you please **show us** the structure of the table in question (columns and their datatypes) and possibly sample date *before* the update, and what you expect as output?

Comment: the number is also existed in a different table in the same database

Comment: Can you also explain why, if you can derive this information, you need to store it? Seems redundant to me unless the point is to drop the file# column.

Comment: Okay, so please show us *both* tables. Right now it sounds like it's just one table. Please be specific, show us table structure, sample data, and desired results. [Help us help you](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/) or your problem will probably be closed.

Comment: so i need to use a value from this table (dbo.tblJob) in the column (BHID) and do all the multiplications to it and add it all other tables (10 other tables) in the column (jobID)

Comment: the main point is to add the file # to each ID in all tables that is automatically generated by SQLserver so if i want to merge the data to an another database that is exactly the same but different data, it would not miss up and i would know how each row came from which file

Comment: Please update the question. Nobody wants to read through word problems posted as after-thought comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [renumber primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230006/renumber-primary-key)

Answer (score 4):

Is it something as simple as this?

```
UPDATE dbo.table SET col = [file#] * 100 + col;
```

If it's from a different table:

```
UPDATE destination
  SET destination.col = source.[file#] * 100 + destination.col
  FROM dbo.table AS destination
  INNER JOIN dbo.other_table AS source
  ON [some join condition that is anyone's guess];
```

Comment: Now that would be *too easy* - there's gotta be more to it :-)

Comment: it is from a different table indeed