# How renumber a column after deleting a record

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, vb.net

My temporary table has a column holding a sequential numeric "row number".

How can I create a update this "row number" column when a record is deleted from the table?

Example

```
ID    Name    Row_Number
1     Jack    1
14    John    2
17    Bella   3
```

If I delete record with ID=14, I'd like record with ID=17 to be updated to be row_number 2

I've tried this:

```
SET @deletestr = ' DELETE FROM  ' + @tablename
        + ' where isnull(ltrim(rtrim([Row_Number])),0)=isnull(ltrim(rtrim(@originalRow_Number)),0)'
```

Comment: Similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230006/renumber-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the below, after the record is deleted, to renumber the table.

```
UPDATE x
SET x.row_number = x.new_row_number
FROM ( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Id) AS new_row_number, row_number    
    FROM @tableName
) x
```

Comment: unfortunately the Row number is done in VB so I can't control it in the SQL Database like this.

Comment: Ok - can you give more detail to question, as it's not currently clear what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @deletestr = ' DELETE FROM  ' + @tablename
            + ' where isnull(ltrim(rtrim([Row_Number])),0)=isnull(ltrim(rtrim(@originalRow_Number)),0)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you don't bother, because row numbers are [easy to derive](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#rank.rows) and a nuisance to maintain.

Any SQL solution to your question will involve a self-join, because that's the way to find the next lowest value.  By producing your row number with a Select, you save yourself some work and the server the overhead of updating the column.