# Disable Foreign key constraint on a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Can i temporarily disable a foreign key constraint. How do i do this?

Comment: Check also this related question: [Can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To temporarily disable a constraint (foreign keys are constraints):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT MyConstraint
```

To re-enable a constraint

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable CHECK CONSTRAINT MyConstraint
```

Comment: be warned this will fail if your data is not referntially in tact.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, this is why you need "Alter table" permissions when you [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) data into a table. Using the default configuration, check constraints and foreign keys are not checked.