# SQL how to check database data validity?

Tags: sql, validation

Is there a simple way to run a check on the databases after turning constrains back on, to check things like:

foreign keys still exist in their primary tables, 
primary key are unique,
etc...

I am working with MS-SQL Server 2005.

Comment: SQL Server would not allow you to turn on the constraint, if the data is not valid...

Comment: @Naveed: actually it does. You have to explicitly specify to recheck after they are re-enabled...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098554/sql-server-how-to-make-server-check-all-its-check-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mitch Wheat linked to the correct answer.

```
DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS WITH ALL_CONSTRAINTS
```