# Check that all foreign key values match an existing primary key value

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I am quite new to databases.

Is there a simple way to check on all tables of a DB if all foreign key values match an existing primary key value ?

Actually I am using a tool (Red Gate) to move many data of many tables from a database to another. I would like to check some kind of consistency after the work is complete.

The SQL script generated by the tool starts with `ALTER TABLE ... NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ...`, and ends with `ALTER TABLE ... CHECK CONSTRAINT ...`, maybe the work was already done by the script...

Any help greatly appreciated !

Comment: If it's `WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT` the statement validates the constraint. Check [Can you trust your constraints?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2007/03/29/can-you-trust-your-constraints.aspx) for an explanation

Comment: @Panagiotis : Thanks for the link. I get `The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint ....`  :)

Comment: Found maybe a related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098554/sql-server-how-to-make-server-check-all-its-check-constraints

Comment: Your comment to Panagiotis is unintelligible. DId his comment answer your question?

Comment: @philipxy : to answer your comment, I have found what I needed in Panagiotis' comment and in the related question I mention. In the second sentence of my comment, I was somehow telling my story to the community by saying the script I was using (generated by the tool) was braking foreign key relationships in my database. This is why i put a smiley :)