# How do I drop all foreign-key constraints on a table in Sql Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I drop all foreign-key constraints on a table in SQL Server 2000 using T-SQL?

Answer (score 14):

If simply disabling constraints is an option here, you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all
```

then you can switch them back on simply using:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all
```

If you want to disable constrains in all tables you can use:

```
-- disable all constraints
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"

-- enable all constraints
exec sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

More in the question: [Can foreign key constraints be
   temporarily disabled using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-tsql)

But if you need to drop constraints permanently you can use [this script posted on databasejurnal.com](http://www.databasejournal.com/scripts/article.php/1502751/Drop-All-Constraints.htm).

Just modify it slightly to only drop the foreign keys

```
create proc sp_drop_fk_constraints
    @tablename  sysname
as
-- credit to: douglas bass

set nocount on

declare @constname  sysname,
    @cmd        varchar(1024)

declare curs_constraints cursor for
    select  name
    from    sysobjects 
    where   xtype in ('F')
    and (status & 64) = 0
    and     parent_obj = object_id(@tablename)

open curs_constraints

fetch next from curs_constraints into @constname
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    select @cmd = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tablename + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @constname
    exec(@cmd)
    fetch next from curs_constraints into @constname
end

close curs_constraints
deallocate curs_constraints

return 0
```

Comment: You can use this statement as well....
 `SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) +
       ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + [name]
     FROM sys.foreign_keys 
     WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id) = 'dbo' AND 
           OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) = '<table>' `

Answer (score 4):

Here you go: (not tested on SQL2000, but should be ok)

Generates 'disables':

```
SELECT  'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys 
   WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].' + FK +''') 
   AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].' + PT + ''')) 
   ALTER TABLE ' + PT + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ' + FK + ';'
FROM 
(SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id) as FK,
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) as PT
    FROM [sys].[foreign_key_columns] ) T
ORDER BY FK
```

Generates 'enables':

```
SELECT  'ALTER TABLE ' + PT + ' WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ' + FK + ';'
FROM 
(SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(constraint_object_id) as FK,
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) as PT
    FROM [sys].[foreign_key_columns] ) T
ORDER BY FK
```

Update: Oops, I thought you wanted it for all tables  :)  You can just modify above for your single table.

Comment: The system tables are different but named similarly in SQL Server 2000: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260604%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that there is no easy way to drop constraints on a table in SQL Server 2000.  That said, there are plenty of people who have written scripts that can identify and remove/disable/recreate foreign key constraints.  One example is at http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1376 - but I haven't tested it on SQL Server 2000.

EDIT: Here is another [example](http://sqlservernation.com/blogs/admin/archive/2009/03/24/how-to-disable-and-enable-foreign-keys.aspx) that generates drop/create scripts for you.