# How to drop all Foreign Key constraints in all tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to write sql command to drop all constraints in all tables. I searched on the internet and found the following which works fine if the database is small and not complex.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(254) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = @name) 

WHILE @name is not null 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
    WHILE @constraint IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @schema + '.[' + RTRIM(@name) +'] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(@constraint) +']' 
        EXEC (@SQL) 
        PRINT 'Dropped FK Constraint: ' + @constraint + ' on ' + @name 
        SELECT @constraint = (SELECT TOP 1 CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @constraint AND TABLE_NAME = @name ORDER BY CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
    END 
SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE constraint_catalog=DB_NAME() AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = @name) 
END 
GO
```

It does not work if I run it with a more complex database or even AdventureWork. It shows some erros like below.

```
Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'FK_ap_invoice_modification_type_id' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
Msg 3725, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The constraint 'PK_ap_invoice' is being referenced by table '_drop_now_ap_invoice_detail', foreign key constraint 'FK_ap_invoice_detail_ap_invoice'.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

The reason is because some FKs are referenced by other table. I have to run this script for a couple times until the database is clean.

I want to know how can I clear all FKs in the database.

Comment: According to your title you want to remove foreign keys. But your last question ask for a "clear everything", including tables, stored procedures, functions. What do you mean with that?

Comment: Although I am sure, you must have checked for similar questions, but I would request you to revisit the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1438933/1268844

Comment: @Yaroslav Thank you for point out. I am full-load with tasks. I just update my question details to match it with the title.

Comment: It yields same result as my query. "Msg 2801, Level 16, State 1, Procedure XXX, Line 31
The definition of object 'XXX' has changed since it was compiled."

Answer (score 38):

There is lot of information about the subject all around. Check [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639982/1297603) by @AaronBertrand. It talks about temporary disabling the foreign keys but reading it all and modifying at will you will have a nice script to play with and achieve a lot.

From my side I can propose 2 different scripts to get all foreign keys. On both cases uncomment the `--EXEC (@SQL)` to execute your `ALTER` code. Or you can wait until it prints all the alter clauses and then copy paste to execute them.

First one uses the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to get the constraints:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)=''
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(FK.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(FK.TABLE_NAME) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(C.CONSTRAINT_NAME) +'];' + CHAR(13)
--SELECT K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME, FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME, PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME, PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME, Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 INNER JOIN (
            SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
             INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
           ) PT
    ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME

--EXEC (@SQL)

PRINT @SQL
```

This one using different system views and a CTE table.

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(4000)=''
;WITH ReferencingFK AS 
(
    SELECT fk.Name AS 'FKName', OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) 'ParentTable',
            cpa.name 'ParentColumnName', OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) 'ReferencedTable',
            cref.name 'ReferencedColumnName'
    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns cpa ON fkc.parent_object_id = cpa.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id = cpa.column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns cref ON fkc.referenced_object_id = cref.object_id AND fkc.referenced_column_id = cref.column_id
)
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'ALTER TABLE ' + ParentTable + ' DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(FKName) +'];' + CHAR(13)
--SELECT FKName, ParentTable, ParentColumnName, ReferencedTable, ReferencedColumnName
  FROM ReferencingFK
 WHERE ReferencedTable = 'Employee'
 ORDER BY ParentTable, ReferencedTable, FKName

--EXEC (@SQL) 

PRINT @SQL
```

Comment: You should use `varchar(max)` and `'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(FK.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(FK.TABLE_NAME) + '` to avoid syntax errors.

Answer (score 36):

Here's a short and sweet script I use (on SQL Server 2008 and up) to remove all foreign keys that also takes into account the object's schema:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    select 
        'alter table ' + quotename(schema_name(schema_id)) + '.' +
        quotename(object_name(parent_object_id)) +
        ' drop constraint '+quotename(name) + ';'
    from sys.foreign_keys
    for xml path('')
);
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: This worked great. Note that on SQL Server Express Edition you need to define your parameter as `nvarchar`, using `varchar` will throw the following error: 
`Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.`
This may be true of some of the newest SQL Server versions as well, but I'm unable to test.

Answer (score 14):

I have improved the first script provided by @Yaroslav and the script provided by @Quandary so they now works for databases whose SQL query to drop all foreign keys one by one exceeds the size allocated for the `SQL` variable (`4000` or `MAX` characters).

The altered scripts drop `5` foreign keys per iteration (just to be safe, implemented by adding `TOP 5`). The scripts stop when there is no foreign key left to drop (the `SQL` variable stays empty after running the `SELECT`).

First script by @Yaroslav

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(4000)
IterationStart:
SET @SQL=''
SELECT TOP 5 @SQL = @SQL + 'ALTER TABLE ' + FK.TABLE_NAME + ' DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(C.CONSTRAINT_NAME) +'];' + CHAR(13)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 INNER JOIN (
            SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
             INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
           ) PT
    ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
IF @SQL <> ''
BEGIN
  EXEC(@SQL)
  GOTO IterationStart
END
```

Script by @Quandary

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) 

IterationStart:
SET @sql = '' 

SELECT TOP 5 @sql = @sql + 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(KCU1.TABLE_NAME) 
    + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME) + '; ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS RC 

INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU1 
    ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG  
    AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
    AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 

IF @SQL <> ''
BEGIN
  EXEC(@SQL)
  GOTO IterationStart
END
```

Comment: I used the script by @Quandary in your answer and it worked perfectly. Kudos

Answer (score 8):

Most simple variant:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) 
SET @sql = N'' 

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(KCU1.TABLE_SCHEMA) 
    + N'.' + QUOTENAME(KCU1.TABLE_NAME) 
    + N' DROP CONSTRAINT ' -- + QUOTENAME(rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA)  + N'.'  -- not in MS-SQL
    + QUOTENAME(rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME) + N'; ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS RC 

INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU1 
    ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG  
    AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
    AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 


-- PRINT @sql 
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the INFORMATION_SCHEMA solution mentioned by @Yaroslav, but had too many foreign key constants in my database to fit them all into a varchar(MAX). So I had to modify the script to use a temporary table and a cursor instead.

Also, I added `[]` around the table name.

```
DECLARE @SQL TABLE (Command VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT @SQL
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + FK.TABLE_NAME + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + RTRIM(C.CONSTRAINT_NAME) +'];' + CHAR(13)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
    ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU
    ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 INNER JOIN (
            SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
              FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
             INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2
                ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
            WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
           ) PT
    ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME

DECLARE cmdCursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT Command FROM @SQL
OPEN cmdCursor
DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX)

FETCH NEXT FROM cmdCursor INTO @Command
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @Command
    EXEC (@Command)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cmdCursor INTO @Command
END

CLOSE cmdCursor;
DEALLOCATE cmdCursor;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #Commands (Command VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT #Commands
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA)
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(KCU1.TABLE_NAME)
    + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME) + '; '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS RC

INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KCU1
    ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE ORDINAL_POSITION=1

--SELECT * FROM #Commands

DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE curCommand CURSOR FOR
SELECT Command FROM #Commands

OPEN curCommand

FETCH NEXT FROM curCommand INTO @Command

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
BEGIN

    EXEC(@Command)
    FETCH NEXT FROM curCommand INTO @Command

END

CLOSE curCommand
DEALLOCATE curCommand

DROP TABLE #Commands
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: For databases with a lot of constraints other solutions mentioned failed but this one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

See Pinal's answer from this link, it is very helpful

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/04/11/sql-server-drop-all-the-foreign-key-constraint-in-database-create-all-the-foreign-key-constraint-in-database/

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @table TABLE(
RowId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
ForeignKeyConstraintName NVARCHAR(200),
ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema NVARCHAR(200),
ForeignKeyConstraintTableName NVARCHAR(200),
ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName NVARCHAR(200),
PrimaryKeyConstraintName NVARCHAR(200),
PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema NVARCHAR(200),
PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName NVARCHAR(200),
PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName NVARCHAR(200)
)
INSERT INTO @table(ForeignKeyConstraintName, ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema, ForeignKeyConstraintTableName, ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName)
SELECT
U.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
U.TABLE_SCHEMA,
U.TABLE_NAME,
U.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE U
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C
ON U.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
UPDATE @table SET
PrimaryKeyConstraintName = UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM
@table T
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS R
ON T.ForeignKeyConstraintName = R.CONSTRAINT_NAME
UPDATE @table SET
PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema = TABLE_SCHEMA,
PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName = TABLE_NAME
FROM @table T
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C
ON T.PrimaryKeyConstraintName = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
UPDATE @table SET
PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName = COLUMN_NAME
FROM @table T
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE U
ON T.PrimaryKeyConstraintName = U.CONSTRAINT_NAME
--SELECT * FROM @table
--DROP CONSTRAINT:
SELECT
'
ALTER TABLE [' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableName + ']
DROP CONSTRAINT [' + ForeignKeyConstraintName + ']

GO'
FROM
@table
```