# Generic SQL Query for Empty Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm searching for a **generic** SQL query that replaces the following procedures:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------  

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Dropping existing tables
-- --------------------------------------------------
```

Example:

The following query drops foreign keys for specific table. Can it be converted to a generic one? (Please don't suggest dropping the whole database as I don't have permissions.)

```
SELECT 
'ALTER TABLE ' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('Student')
```

**Question**:

How can I empty a database *without* dropping it?

---

**Edit**: Wait Wait, it's not a duplication question! The other question was about emptying rows ( or data ONLY ) keeping relations and tables. I'm trying to drop all data, tables & relations *without* dropping the database itself!

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Emptying database without dropping it, Godaddy Rules!

Comment: Wait Wait, It's not a duplication one! other question was about emptying rows ( data ), I'm here for dropping database without really dropping it!

Comment: What do you mean by "**Generic**"?

Comment: Do you want to guarantee that the database is in a known state, i.e. no user objects (tables, SPs, UDFs, ...), all options set to specific values, all security reset, ... ?

Comment: Generic, run on any database connection string, emptying it without providing tables names or relations names

Comment: I would use GoDaddy's backup/restore to repeatedly refresh a database back to an empty state, ie Create a new empty db once, back it up, and then periodically restore to a known (and empty) state.

Comment: Thanks @NathanSkerl, the only defect in your suggestion is that GoDaddy's database restore take up-to 15 minutes and a minimum of 3 minutes, I went with that for 3 days but it has a really bad performance wise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer [How to drop all Foreign Key constraints in all tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721823/how-to-drop-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-all-tables)

This will drop your foreign keys from all tables, you can either add a drop table into the loop, or create a new loop afterwards to drop the tables