# Delete all foreign keys in database(MySql)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I would like to rename a column in a table that is a foreign key to many tables. Apparently this is only possible if you delete the constraints, as I found out in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014498/renaming-foreign-key-columns-in-mysql/2014519#2014519).

I dont want to delete all the constratints manually is there a way to delete all the foreign key constraints in the database?

I have also tried `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` but I still cant rename the column.

Comment: If you don't know what you're deleting, how are you going to recreate all the FKs?

Comment: What do you mean by all `foreign key constraints`? You have to consider if you have index on these columns as well.. check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438654/how-do-i-drop-all-foreign-key-constraints-on-a-table-in-sql-server-2000 : it's for sql server, you may find a similar syntax for altering

Comment: just all the foreign keys, I can recreate the FKeys because I use http://www.doctrine-project.org/ and have the models that will recreate the tables

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Executing the following query

```
select * from information_schema.key_column_usage
```

will show you all the constraints (with the column name, constraint type, table and schema) that exist in your database. You'll notice these columns:

```
CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
CONSTRAINT_NAME
TABLE_CATALOG
TABLE_SCHEMA
TABLE_NAME
COLUMN_NAME
ORDINAL_POSITION
POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT
REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA
REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
```

Then, if you're planning to delete each constraint you have referencing your column, you should  consider the **REFERENCED_*** columns and run something like:

```
DELETE FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
WHERE 
    REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA='myschema'
    AND
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME='mytable'
    AND
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME='mycolumn'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/key-column-usage-table.html

Comment: Sadly this will not work because `information_schema` tables are not writeable

Comment: This kind of approach (even if the user had the permission, which it does not) will just left a gazzilion of trash values in so many tables. This solution just does not do the job

Answer (score 40):

You can use this SQL to generate ALTER TABLES (`!!YOUR_SCHEMA_HERE!!` needs to be replaced by your schema):

```
SELECT concat('alter table `',table_schema,'`.`',table_name,'` DROP FOREIGN KEY ',constraint_name,';')
FROM information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY'
AND table_schema='!!YOUR_SCHEMA_HERE!!';
```

It will generate SQL like this:

```
alter table `viewpoint_test`.`answer_code` DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_answer_code_codebook_item1;
alter table `viewpoint_test`.`answer_code` DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_answer_code_questionary_answer1;
alter table `viewpoint_test`.`codebook` DROP FOREIGN KEY codebook_ibfk_1;
...
```

By "schema name", I mean your database name. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try using As Like of Following ..

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
DROP FOREIGN KEY fieldName;
ADD FOREIGN KEY (newForignKeyFieldName);
```

Also you can try with Reference Key.As like .....

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
DROP FOREIGN KEY fieldName;
ADD FOREIGN KEY (newForignKeyFieldName)
REFERENCES anotherTableName(reference_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query will build the correct syntax automatically.
Make sure you put your real DB schema name in the `WHERE` condition.
Just execute each line returned and all your `FOREIGN KEYS` will be gone.

I leave the reverse (adding them back) as an exercise for you.

```
SELECT CONCAT("alter table ", TABLE_NAME," drop foreign key ", CONSTRAINT_NAME,"; ") AS runMe
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='MY_SCHEMA_NAME' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME <> 'PRIMARY';
```

If you need it to be schema independent, you can write:
`TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()` to get the current active DB name

Answer (score 0):

I was still having some issues after finding this thread, but I have seemed to find a workflow that works for me.

## Database Deletion

If you are using MySQL Workbench, you will need to turn SAFE UPDATE off by doing the following 3 steps:

1. MySql Workbench > Preferences > SQL EDITOR > (bottom of settings)
2. turn the SAFE UPDATE off
3. then log out of your connection and reconnect

### Steps to start purge database and start new

1. Delete all data from tables

(This MySQL script will create a DELETE FROM script for each table in your database.)

`SELECT concat('DELETE FROM ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';')
FROM information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE table_schema='!!TABLE_SCHEMA!!';`

Copy the output of this and run it. You might need this line-by-line.

2. Delete all Foreign Keys from your tables

(This MySql script will create na ALTER TABLE _ DROP FOREIGN KEY script for each table in your database.)

`SELECT concat('alter table ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',constraint_name,';')
FROM information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE constraint_type='FOREIGN KEY'
AND table_schema='!!TABLE_SCHEMA!!';`

Copy the output of this and run it. You might need this line-by-line.

After you've done this, you SHOULD be able to run your DROP DATABASE script.