# How to delete all procedures of a database in mysql5

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql

I want to delete all procedures from my MySQL database `sbnmaster`. How should I write a query for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027832/drop-all-stored-procedures-in-mysql-or-using-temporary-stored-procedures

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
USE sbnmaster;

SELECT CONCAT('DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ', SPECIFIC_NAME, ';') AS StorePrecedure 
FROM information_schema.ROUTINES R 
WHERE R.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' 
AND R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();
```

Comment: I had to add a semicolon to the concat to get it to work with several procs: `SELECT CONCAT("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ",SPECIFIC_NAME,";") AS StorePrecedure `

Answer (score 7):

Not sure that it is correct, but seems it works -

```
DELETE FROM mysql.proc WHERE db = 'sbnmaster' AND type = 'PROCEDURE';
```