# SQL statement to truncate all data from all tables in the database

Tags: sql, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate all tables in a MySQL database in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command)

how to delete all the data from all tables in the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command

Answer (score 0):

use like this,

```
TRUNCATE `table1`;
TRUNCATE `table2`;
TRUNCATE `table3`;
TRUNCATE `table4`;
```

Comment: Thanks pal, but i got many tables, so i thought some way out to do it at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you have scripted creation of empty tables, it may be faster to drop and recreate the database, depending on number of tables. It is less typing for sure :-) -

Comment: i tried it but the auto generated ids are not set to zero. they continue from the last id that was truncated.

Comment: Add this to your table creation script:

ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in single statements.  You could create a loop, assigning the next table name to a variable and then use dynamic sql to execute the `TRUNCATE` statement.