# How to delete all the tables in a MySQL database?

Tags: sql, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate all tables in a MySQL database in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command)

I need to delete, or drop, all the tables in a MySQL database with single command without knowing the tablenames. Is this possible?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
drop database YOUR_DATABASE;
/* this will delete all the tables for this database */

create database YOUR_DATABASE;
/* added back the database namespace */
```

Comment: requires the specific right to drop it though

Comment: for this question i got another solution instead of drop database. i got all the list of tables using show tables and drop the tables one by one.

Comment: alright, but that is not using single command :)

Comment: phpadmin not allowed me to use drop, anything else.

Comment: For the longest time, I thought this would reset permissions for some reason! ;_; all the wasted minutes.

Comment: It will reset your character set / collation for the database though, so be careful.

Comment: I do this by phpmyadmin (I check foreign key check false) .Because **You cannot always get permission to create database**. Espesially, in **shared hosting enviornment**. So in my view, what to do is to select all tables from phpmyadmin and drop it. Disclaimer: May this answer OP looking for. But not suggestible as a general solution to all.

Comment: now working in phpmyadmin of my ISP

Comment: I know this works but this is not a right answer :|

Answer (score 2):

Rather long, but try this command (after replacing the obvious things):

```
mysql --user=YOUR_USERNAME --password=YOUR_PASSWORD -BNe "show tables" YOUR_DBSCHEMA_NAME | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/,$//' | awk '{print "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " $1 ";SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"}' | mysql --user=YOUR_USERNAME --password=YOUR_PASSWORD YOUR_DBSCHEMA_NAME
```

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted (I don't think that should be allowed without a comment!), but this is great and better than [other linked answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8912749/623519) as it deals with foreign key checks too. Thanks.