# mySQL: command to truncate all tables

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL.

What is the **mysql command** to **truncate all tables** of my database?

I mean what is the mysql command which **empty all tables** in my DB **not drop** all tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate all tables in a MySQL database in one command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code found [here](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/06/how-to-truncate-all-or-some-of-tables.html)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE TruncateTables()
BEGIN
DECLARE done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE truncate_command VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE truncate_cur
 CURSOR FOR /*This is the query which selects the tables we want to truncate*/
  SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ',table_name)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'prefix_%';
DECLARE
  CONTINUE HANDLER FOR
  SQLSTATE '02000'
   SET done = TRUE;

OPEN truncate_cur;

truncate_loop: LOOP
 FETCH truncate_cur INTO truncate_command;
 SET @truncate_command = truncate_command;

 IF done THEN
  CLOSE truncate_cur;
  LEAVE truncate_loop;
 END IF;

 /*Main part - preparing and executing the statement*/
 PREPARE truncate_command_stmt FROM @truncate_command;
 EXECUTE truncate_command_stmt;

END LOOP;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way is to use Navicat.

Use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to check all tables. Then right click and choose "truncate table".