# Truncate or Delete tables from the MySql database

Tags: mysql, truncate, sql-delete, sql-drop

I have a databse called **store** having 100 tables having too much `foreign key references` with tables, having thousands of records.

**Problem**:
Is it possible something like **truncate** to delete all the rows of all the tables in a single query.

I tried but I am not able to find the exact way to achieve this when I try to `TRUNCATE TABLE` it gives me error: `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` which is expected too.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this, or suggest me the better way to do this.

Comment: If you want to delete all data you can simply recreate the DB. Delete the database and run the create script again.

Comment: This may help you? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1912813/1983854

Comment: Take a look at http://punkave.com/window/2009/05/27/how-to-add-on-delete-cascade-to-an-existing-mysql-table-without-dropping-any-existing-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this before deleting:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

When finished, reset it to 1:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```