# MySQL Query to truncate All Tables ignoring all constraints?

Tags: mysql

I would like to truncate all the rows of the tables in a mysql database.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; -- Disable foreign key checking.
-- Need MySQL Query to iterater/loop and truncate all the tables or delete all the rows of the -- table
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; -- Enable foreign key checking.
```

Could someone help me with the query please?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate all tables in a MySQL database in one command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command)

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17738975/1124929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because u used this table primary key as foreign key in some other table.
**Delete values from child table and then try to truncate parent table **

eg: country table -> country id(primary key),name
people table -> people id(primary key), People name, country id(foreign key)

delete values from people table and then try to truncate country table :)

Comment: I need a generic query to disable all constraints and truncate all rows..i.e i want the structure to be maintained but all the rows of the all the tables in a database to be delete by ignoring any constraints such as foreign key, primary key, unique key etc.,

Comment: Your question is similar to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query).

Comment: the query should be generic to be used in any mysql database to truncate all the tables..specificying names will make the query as DB dependent.

Comment: This does not answer the question (which is actually "how do I truncate all tables"), but provides a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This query would do it:

```
SELECT Concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ', TABLE_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```