# Delete all tables of a single database

Tags: mysql

I need to delete all the tables from my database name "marketing" for magento. I am a beginner so I don’t know much.

please help me , as I can not drop my database.

Thanks,

Divyang

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate all tables in a MySQL database in one command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command)

Comment: you wanted to drop tables? or you want to delete records from  all your DB database tables?

Comment: i have tried with "   mysql  -uroot -ppassword -Nse 'show tables' typo3_6 | while read table; do mysql -e "truncate table $table" typo3_6; done    "  as root is my user and password is my password . but got  Access denied for user error.

Comment: @divyang , you can drop the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below single line command directly from linux server but first test on any testing environment before executing it for safe side.

```
mysql -uroot -p<pass> -Nse 'show tables' margeting | while read table; do mysql -uroot -p<pass> marketing -e "drop table $table"; done
```

If you want to do it manually then use below steps-

First get all tables-

```
show tables from margeting;
```

Now prepare drop command you can do it in excel etc like-

```
use marketing;
drop table mytable1;
drop table mytable2;
```

Now you can execute these statements from anywhere like from any query browser etc-

Comment: Thanks mysql -uroot -p<pass> -Nse 'show tables' margeting | while read table; do mysql -uroot -p<pass> marketing -e "drop table $table"; done works

Comment: if it helps you then you may accept it as answer by green tick.   :)