# how can I truncate all my databases without changing the tables structures?

Tags: mysql

I have quite some databases built. I want to empty them without changing their structure. Is there a way to do it? if so, can you please guide me how to do that?

Comment: you do know you can't truncate databases but only tables

Comment: A) Find list of table names. B) Truncate them. You can do this with a text editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate all tables in a MySQL database in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command)