# Delete all data from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a db with 100 tables. I want to delete data from all tables using mysql command or in phpmyadmin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate all tables in a MySQL database in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command)

Comment: If you're doing this because you want to reset the database after tests, you can instead run all the tests in a transaction and rollback at the end.

Answer (score 2):

- Backup your database structure (use `mysqldump` with [`--no-data`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) command line option).
- Drop database.
- Restore database from the dump.

This method have no problems with FOREIGN KEY relations. Rather than DELETE/TRUNCATE usage where you must clear the tables content in definite order (if you'd clear master table before slave one then the deletion will fail due to referential constraint violation).

Answer (score 1):

Use information_schema.TABLES make dynamic query and exeute.

```
select concat('delete from ',TABLE_NAME,';') from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='databasename';
```

Comment: [`truncate table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html) will be significantly faster than `delete`.

Comment: yes better idea change in concat('delete from ',TABLE_NAME,';') to concat('truncate table ',TABLE_NAME,';')

Comment: I want to delete all tables data.

Comment: is there some way to delete data from all tables or at the time of import only import table structure/columns

Answer (score 0):

or try this one

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

SET @TABLES = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('delete from ', table_name,';') INTO @TABLES FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'databasename' and table_name in ('tbl_audit_trail','tbl_celery');
  

SET @TABLES= replace( @TABLES,',','');
select @TABLES;
```

copy the result and execute

Comment: It will be better to add `SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN=32768;` in case there are a lot of tables, or they are with long names. I had a scenario with a database with about 130 tables and the default MAX_LEN wasn't enough. 

And do not forget to return the foreign key checks `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;` after the end of the script.