# SQL Management Studio Insert statement confliction

Tags: ssms

I'm working on creating a development database for my boss. I have the SQL script that creates all the tables, but now I have loads of data to import. There are 5 tables total in the database, and their ID's are related to eachother like so:

*Note: I'm not allowed to share info like database/table names*

```
Table1
+-- Table2
    +-- Table3
        +-- Table4
            +-- Table5
```

Meaning that `Table 5` has a field that points to a `Table 4`'s ID, and so on.

So I'm doing a bunch of inserts like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2] (Table1_ID, AnotherField) VALUES (159268, 408659)
```

But it throws this exception for each one:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_TABLE2_TABLE1". The conflict occurred in database "--removed by author--", table "dbo.TABLE1", column 'TABLE1_ID'.
```

**EDIT:**
So the problem was that I needed to insert the data in Table1 first. So my Boss found some data that will suffice for Table1... So Problem solved :)

Comment: please, insert data to the TABLE1, then TABLE2...

Comment: But there is no data for `TABLE1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really much to add - the error message is pretty clear.

You are trying to insert an ID value in to Table2 however the that ID value doesn't exist in Table1.  Hence the error message.

You need to insert the data in to Table1 before you insert in to Table2

EDIT:

<strike>If there is no data for Table1 then the database constraints are poorly thought out.  You will have to remove the constraint from Table2.</strike>

You will have to ask them for the data for Table1 then.

Comment: We're re-constructing a company's database in SQL Management Studio, and they only gave us the data for tables 2, 4 and 5

Answer (score 0):

1. You should do a top-down import: first import all records from `Table1`, then `Table2`, etc.
2. Or, to make things easier, and have a faster experience, you could disable all your constraints before executing, and re-enable them after completion. Please, take a look here: [How can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-tsql)

EDIT:

Well, if you don't have `Table1` data all you can do is remove all foreign-key constraints that reference `Table1` (probably from `Table2`). Or you could try generating "fake" `Table1` data, considering all distinct `Table1` IDs available on `Table2` (aaarrgh).

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily disable the foreign key constraint, do the insert, and then re-enable it using `CHECK` and `NOCHECK`.

`WITH NOCHECK CONSTRAINT` disables the constraint and allows an insert that would normally violate the constraint.

`WITH CHECK CONSTRAINT` re-enables the constraint.

Here's a [detailed explanation](http://odetocode.com/Articles/79.aspx) of how to do this.