# drop and recreate ALL constraints combine with sp_MSForEachTable sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm doing some test data loading with SSIS into our data warehouse and have come across the old chestnut of foreign key constraints.  I'm going to be removing/adding all data looking for data issues in my local test environment.  Therefore I could care less about referential integrity at this point... I came across this handy little query:

```
-- disable referential integrity
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NO CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO 

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?' 
GO 

-- enable referential integrity again 
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO
```

The only problem is it is useless if you have foreign key constraints as you have to actually drop them.  Is there any way of combining this query with something that will Drop/Recreate all constraints???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no

You have to DELETE tables with foreign keys

```
-- disable referential integrity
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NO CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO 
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE ?' 
GO 
-- enable referential integrity again 
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO
```

Or, script and DROP your constraints first, add tjem back later. 
To that end, see this article to ["Script out your foreign keys"](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2009/08/07/Script-out-your-foreign-keys.aspx)

Comment: on a small db doesn't matter about using DELETE so that will work... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8):

```
   --Drop and Recreate Foreign Key Constraints

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @table TABLE(
   RowId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
   ForeignKeyConstraintName NVARCHAR(200),
   ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema NVARCHAR(200),
   ForeignKeyConstraintTableName NVARCHAR(200),
   ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintName NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName NVARCHAR(200),
   PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName NVARCHAR(200)    
)

INSERT INTO @table(ForeignKeyConstraintName, ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema, ForeignKeyConstraintTableName, ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName)
SELECT 
   U.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
   U.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
   U.TABLE_NAME, 
   U.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE U
      INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C
         ON U.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
   C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'

UPDATE @table SET
   PrimaryKeyConstraintName = UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM 
   @table T
      INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS R
         ON T.ForeignKeyConstraintName = R.CONSTRAINT_NAME

UPDATE @table SET
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema  = TABLE_SCHEMA,
   PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName  = TABLE_NAME
FROM @table T
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C
      ON T.PrimaryKeyConstraintName = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME

UPDATE @table SET
   PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName = COLUMN_NAME
FROM @table T
   INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE U
      ON T.PrimaryKeyConstraintName = U.CONSTRAINT_NAME

--SELECT * FROM @table

--DROP CONSTRAINT:
SELECT
   '
   ALTER TABLE [' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableName + '] 
   DROP CONSTRAINT ' + ForeignKeyConstraintName + '

   GO'
FROM
   @table

--ADD CONSTRAINT:
SELECT
   '
   ALTER TABLE [' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + ForeignKeyConstraintTableName + '] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT ' + ForeignKeyConstraintName + ' FOREIGN KEY(' + ForeignKeyConstraintColumnName + ') REFERENCES [' + PrimaryKeyConstraintTableSchema + '].[' + PrimaryKeyConstraintTableName + '](' + PrimaryKeyConstraintColumnName + ')

   GO'
FROM
   @table

GO
```