# How do I "run" a command in a stored procedure thats generated from a select statement?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, foreign-keys, truncate

I am using this script https://stackoverflow.com/a/9452317/449156 to generate statements to drop and re-create all my foreign key constraints so I can truncate specific database tables.

This works excellently, however I am wondering how I can incorporate this into a Stored Procedure.
At the moment all that happens is that it generates the command's but doesn't "call or run" them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must execute the statements

if a statement is stored in a var `@ddlStatement`

```
Exec sp_executesql @ddlStatement
```