# ASP.NET MVC EF Seeder can't delete rows because foreign key relationships

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, seeding

I have a seeder for my Entity framework, a function ResetTables(), which deletes all rows from all tables, then reseeds them all.

Foreign key relationships are blocking my delete statements, I managed to get around the issue for awhile by deleting things in a precise order but now, even that's not working.

How can I get around this.

Here's an example of my ResetTables() method

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Badges (Name) VALUES (null)");
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Badges; DBCC CHECKIDENT(Badges, RESEED, 0)");
```

NB: The insert and reseet is just so things get set back to 0 so that my IDs don't climb to high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear database and you don't want to deal with constraints you can [temporarily turn them off, execute your deletion and turn on constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql).