# NOCHECK does not disable foreign key references

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Table creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[details](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [details] [varchar](max) NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[name](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__name__3213E83F0D384EE4] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[details]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [id] FOREIGN KEY([id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[name] ([id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[details] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [id]
GO
```

Table population script

```
insert into name(name) values (newid())
go 100

insert into details (id,details) values(RAND()*10,newid())
Go 1000
```

Table truncation script

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "truncate table ?"
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Taken from [How can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql)

Also tried

```
alter table name nocheck constraint all
truncate table name
```

Both the cases don't allow me to truncate the table since a foreign key reference is there

Error message:

> Cannot truncate table 'dbo.name' because it is being referenced by a
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Is there a way to disable FK constraints, delete all data in the database and reinitialize identities, then reenable FK constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following two scripts for disabling foreign keys. I have not created them, I found them on interwebs, but they worked perfectly for me for the last few years. Unfortunately I can't find the source of them any longer.

references_sp.sql is a stored procedure that need to be created before the other script runs.

references_run.sql is a script that generates a script for disabling/enabling foreign keys.

Note that it's safe to run the script provided here - it does not modify the database (apart from creating and then deleting temporary tables) it just generates another script that drops and re-create the foreign keys.

And now the scripts.

references_sp.sql:

```
USE [master]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*********************************************************************************************
Copyright SQLServerNation.com
*  Author:  Tim Chapman
***********************************************************************************************/
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ShowForeignKeyObjects]
AS
    SELECT 
        OBJECT_NAME(constid) AS ConstraintName,
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkeyid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(fkeyid) + '.' + COL_NAME(fkeyid, fkey) AS ForeignKeyObject,
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(rkeyid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(rkeyid) + '.' + COL_NAME(rkeyid, rkey) AS ReferenceKeyObject, 
        COL_NAME(fkeyid, fkey) AS ForeignKeyColumn,
        COL_NAME(rkeyid, rkey) AS ReferenceKeyColumn, 
        constid AS ConstraintID, 
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkeyid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(fkeyid) AS ForeignKeyTable,         
        fkeyid AS ForeignKeyID, 
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(rkeyid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(rkeyid) AS ReferenceKeyTable,
        rkeyid AS ReferenceKeyID,
        keyno AS KeySequenceNumber
    FROM 
        sysforeignkeys
    ORDER BY 
        OBJECT_NAME(rkeyid) ASC, COL_NAME(rkeyid, rkey)

GO
```

references_run.sql:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FK')>0
  DROP TABLE #FK

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Const')>0
  DROP TABLE #Const

CREATE TABLE #FK
(
  ConstraintName VARCHAR(255),
  ForeignKeyObject VARCHAR(255),
  ReferenceObject VARCHAR(255),
  ForeignKeyColumn VARCHAR(255),
  ReferenceKeyColumn VARCHAR(255),
  ConstraintID INT, 
  ForeignKeyTable VARCHAR(255),
  ForeignKeyID INT, 
  ReferenceKeyTable VARCHAR(255),
  ReferenceKeyID INT, 
  KeySequenceNumber SMALLINT
)

CREATE TABLE #Const
(
  ConstraintID INT, 
  FBuildField VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT(''), 
  RBuildField VARCHAR(2000) DEFAULT(''), 
  CountField SMALLINT 
)

INSERT INTO #FK
EXEC sp_Showforeignkeyobjects

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE  tempcursor
CURSOR
READ_ONLY
FOR 

  SELECT    
    f.ConstraintName ,
    f.ForeignKeyObject ,
    f.ReferenceObject ,
    f.ForeignKeyColumn ,
    f.ReferenceKeyColumn,
    f.ConstraintID , 
    f.ForeignKeyID , 
    f.ReferenceKeyID , 
    f.KeySequenceNumber, 
    f.ForeignKeyTable,
    f.ReferenceKeyTable 
  FROM #FK AS  f
    INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT ConstraintID, MAX(KeySequenceNumber) AS MaxSeq
      FROM #FK AS  k
      GROUP BY k.ConstraintID
    )b ON f.ConstraintID = b.ConstraintID AND f.KeySequenceNumber = b.MaxSeq

DECLARE 
  @ConstraintName VARCHAR(255),
  @ForeignKeyObject VARCHAR(255),
  @ReferenceObject VARCHAR(255),
  @ForeignKeyColumn VARCHAR(255),
  @ReferenceKeyColumn VARCHAR(255),
  @ConstraintID INT, 
  @ForeignKeyID INT, 
  @ReferenceKeyID INT, 
  @KeySequenceNumber SMALLINT, 
  @ForeignKeyTable VARCHAR(255),
  @ReferenceKeyTable VARCHAR(255)

OPEN tempcursor

  FETCH NEXT FROM tempCursor INTO 
  @ConstraintName ,
  @ForeignKeyObject ,
  @ReferenceObject ,
  @ForeignKeyColumn ,
  @ReferenceKeyColumn,
  @ConstraintID , 
  @ForeignKeyID , 
  @ReferenceKeyID, 
  @KeySequenceNumber,
  @ForeignKeyTable ,
  @ReferenceKeyTable 

WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN

  DECLARE  tempcursor2
  CURSOR
  READ_ONLY
  FOR 

    SELECT ConstraintID, ForeignKeyColumn, ReferenceKeyColumn, KeySequenceNumber 
    FROM #FK 
    WHERE ConstraintID = @ConstraintID

    ORDER BY ConstraintID, KeySequenceNumber ASC

  DECLARE @ConstraintID2 INT, @ForeignKeyColumn2 VARCHAR(255), @ReferenceKeyColumn2 VARCHAR(255), @KeySequenceNumber2 SMALLINT
  DECLARE @FKeyBuildField VARCHAR(1000), @RKeyBuildField VARCHAR(1000), @Cnt SMALLINT 

  OPEN tempcursor2

  SELECT @FKeyBuildField = '', @RKeyBuildField = '', @Cnt = 0

  FETCH NEXT FROM tempcursor2 INTO @ConstraintID2 , @ForeignKeyColumn2 , @ReferenceKeyColumn2 , @KeySequenceNumber2
  WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
  BEGIN
    SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    SELECT @FKeyBuildField = @FKeyBuildField  + ISNULL(@ForeignKeyColumn2,'')+ 
      CASE 
        WHEN @ForeignKeyColumn2 IS NULL THEN '' 
      ELSE  
        CASE WHEN @KeySequenceNumber = @KeySequenceNumber2 THEN '' ELSE ',' END
      END

    SELECT @RKeyBuildField = @RKeyBuildField  + ISNULL(@ReferenceKeyColumn2,'')+ 
      CASE 
        WHEN @ReferenceKeyColumn2 IS NULL THEN '' 
      ELSE  
        CASE WHEN @KeySequenceNumber = @KeySequenceNumber2 THEN '' ELSE ',' END
      END

    INSERT INTO #Const
    (   
      ConstraintID , 
      FBuildField , 
      RBuildField, 
      CountField  
    )
    VALUES
    (
      @ConstraintID, 
      @FKeyBuildField,
      @RKeyBuildField,
      @Cnt
    )

    FETCH NEXT FROM tempcursor2 INTO @ConstraintID2 , @ForeignKeyColumn2 , @ReferenceKeyColumn2 , @KeySequenceNumber2
  END
  CLOSE tempcursor2
  DEALLOCATE tempcursor2

  FETCH NEXT FROM tempCursor INTO 
  @ConstraintName ,
  @ForeignKeyObject ,
  @ReferenceObject ,
  @ForeignKeyColumn ,
  @ReferenceKeyColumn,
  @ConstraintID , 
  @ForeignKeyID , 
  @ReferenceKeyID , 
  @KeySequenceNumber ,
  @ForeignKeyTable ,
  @ReferenceKeyTable 
END

CLOSE tempcursor
DEALLOCATE tempcursor

SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + FKTable + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + OBJECT_NAME(a.ConstraintID) AS DropKeys,
'ALTER TABLE ' + FKTable + ' WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ' + OBJECT_NAME(a.ConstraintID) + ' FOREIGN KEY(' + FBuildField + ') REFERENCES ' + RKTable + '(' + RBuildField+')' AS BuildKeys
,*
FROM #Const a
JOIN
(
  SELECT ConstraintID, MAX(countfield) AS maxcount
  FROM #Const
  GROUP BY ConstraintID
) b ON a.ConstraintID = b.ConstraintID  AND a.countfield = b.maxcount
JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT constraintid, '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(foreignkeyid) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(foreignkeyid) + ']' AS FKTable, '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencekeyid) + '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(referencekeyid) + ']' AS RKTable FROM #fk
) c ON a.constraintid = c.constraintid

DROP TABLE #Const
```