# Replace All data in the table with relationship

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck on how to replace all the data in a table that already has relationship.

- I have to tables, Company and Contact. and the PrimaryKeys of these two tables are related to other tables.
- Before, I do anything with Contact, I made a copy of Contact table (select * INTO ContactBK from Contact)
- After I modified some data in Contact, now I like to replace all the data from ContactBK (orginal) back to Contact, but I could not.
- I have tried to use Import in Server Management Studio and select "replace exists data", but it failed.  I also can not delete all the data in Contact table and replace, because the ContactID is tied to others tables.

Comment: Did you try separately inserting, updating, and deleting as appropriate?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: To drop and recreate the foreign keys you can use this script http://stackoverflow.com/a/14995032/284111

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. I will try as I described below. Worst case, I will rebuild the relationship again after replaced the data.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a update from the ContactBAK table using a join approach. If the records are essentially the same with a few fields modified, this should work. For example:

```
UPDATE c SET c.FirstName = bak.FirstName FROM Contacts c
LEFT JOIN ContactsBAK bak ON c.ContactID = bak.ContactID
```

You'll have to modify the fields you want to update and match on the joins of course.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I inserted a bunch of bogus records in the Contact table, modified some records, so you suggestion is only work for update this existing records with the same contactID.  Maybe I need to delete those bogus records that are not match with ContactBK, then use our suggestions.  Thanks again

Comment: The bogus records will not be affected by the join update as they have nothing to join against in the BAK table. I would just delete them.