# Delete tables with foreign key in right order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have do delete some SQL Server 2008R2 tables that are related with foreign keys, is there any way to select the tables I need in the right order so I'll not receive any error of child records because I'm not deleting the data according to the FK?
Thank you.

Comment: I've been using this script http://stackoverflow.com/a/14995032/284111 perhaps not exactly what you need, but you probably can modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the `FOREIGN KEY` Definitions to see if they have `CASCADE DELETE` turned on? If yes, then SQL Server will automatically CASCADE the DELETEs on related Child records.

Comment: we don't have cascade delete turned on so I need to delete them from bottom to top. Thanks!