# How to turn off/on all the foreign keys and triggers in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

It can be needed for inserting and modifying of big amounts of data.

Comment: This may be helpful in globally disabling all foreign key constraints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql

Comment: You should use `ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL` (note the additional `WITH CHECK` option) otherwise existing data in the table will *not* be verified when turning on the constraints. This is extremely dangerous when you turned them off for bulk loading, the loaded data will not be verified without the `WITH CHECK` option!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disable all FKs:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
GO
```

Enable all FKs:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
GO
```

Disable all triggers:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER ALL"
GO
```

Enable all triggers:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER ALL"
GO
```

Of course, note that if you had any FKs/triggers disabled prior to this, the enable script will re-enable these.

Answer (score 0):

To disable all FKs in a table:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

To disable a single FK in a table:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1
```

To enable them replace `NOCHECK` with `CHECK`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable all FK's, and then restore them back to their original state, the following can be used:

**Disable All Constraints**

```
If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempConstraints') is not null Drop Table #tempConstraints;
GO
IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpScriptErrors')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpScriptErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpScriptErrors (Error int)
GO
Create Table #tempConstraints
(
    ConstraintName nVarchar(200),
    TableName nVarchar(200),
    SchemaName nVarchar(200),
    IsNotTrusted bit
);
GO

Begin Tran

Insert into #tempConstraints (ConstraintName, TableName, SchemaName, IsNotTrusted)
Select K.name, object_name(K.parent_object_id), SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id), K.Is_Not_Trusted
FROM sys.foreign_keys K 
    Inner Join sys.tables T on K.parent_object_id = T.object_id
Where is_disabled = 0
Union all
Select K.name, object_name(K.parent_object_id), SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id), K.Is_Not_Trusted
from sys.check_constraints K
    Inner Join sys.tables T on K.parent_object_id = T.object_id
Where is_disabled = 0


--Disable the Constraints.
Print 'Disabling Constraints'
Exec sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL';
```

**Restore Constraints to Original State**

```
Declare @name nvarchar(200);
Declare @table nvarchar(200);
Declare @schema nvarchar(200);
Declare @script nvarchar(max);
Declare @NotTrusted bit;

Declare constraints_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    Select ConstraintName, TableName, SchemaName, IsNotTrusted
    From #tempConstraints;

Open constraints_cursor;

Fetch Next from constraints_cursor
into @name, @table, @schema, @NotTrusted;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    --Restore each of the Constraints back to exactly the state they were in prior to disabling.

    If @NotTrusted = 1
        Set @script = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] WITH NOCHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + @name + ']';
    Else
        Set @script = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + @name + ']';


    exec sp_executesql @script;
    If @@ERROR <> 0
    Begin
        PRINT 'Re-Enabling ' + @name;
        INSERT  INTO #tmpScriptErrors (Error)
        VALUES (1);
    End

    Fetch Next from constraints_cursor
    into @name, @table, @schema, @NotTrusted;
End
Close constraints_cursor;
Deallocate constraints_cursor;

If exists (Select 'x' from #tmpScriptErrors)
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
Else
    COMMIT TRAN;

Drop table #tmpScriptErrors
GO
Drop table #tempConstraints
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Disabling triggers in a single statement

`DISABLE TRIGGER` and `ENABLE TRIGGER` - check MSDN for their syntax. E.g., search google for : DISABLE TRIGGER t-sql

E.g.,
    DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ALL SERVER; -- Disabling all DML triggers defined on server level and all logon triggers

There is no built-in way how to disable all FKs in a single statement.

Comment: Actually, there is. `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'`

Comment: Yes, you're right, but it depends on the definition of a single statement. sp_MSforeachtable is a procedure that has lots of statements inside it. However, I guess an SP call is good enough ...