# Drop all the tables without any Constraint Error in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to DROP all the tables with name starts with particular name, I wrote the script for the same but, when I try to delete the TABLE , I am getting Constraint issue.

So I want the  approach to drop each table, in loop without/ignoring Relationships/Forieng_Key. Please suggested optimized script to perform the same operation. Please share your thoughts.

```
    DECLARE @SqlStatement VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SqlStatement = ''
    Print 'Deleting Tables and Columns from the Agency Table schema'
    SELECT @SqlStatement = 
        COALESCE(@SqlStatement, '') + 'DROP TABLE ['+@agencyName+'].' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ';' + CHAR(13)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @agencyName;

    PRINT @SqlStatement
    --exec(@SqlStatement) -- In this Line I am getting the Foreign Key constraint issue. how do I achieve the functionality.

    --DROP SCHEMA Agency3
```

Comment: you could disable the foreign key constraints:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql

Comment: But the problem is automation, I donno whether table is foreign key  table or priamry key table, I want some generic approach for the same

Comment: you can search all foreign keys for your tables and disable them, after that you can drop your tables

Comment: What If when the iteartion stars with Primary Column table ..

Comment: you iterate first over the foreign keys, and then you iterate over the tables. The PK tables doesnt matter then