# Entity Framework Navigation Property without Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, navigation-properties, ef-fluent-api

I have a code first EF Model with a simple one(PartDetails)-to-many(Parts) relationship.

While the system is offline the lookup (PartDetails) table is purged and re-populated by external job, violating the constraint.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Part>().HasOptional(e => e.PartDetails)
                           .WithMany()
                           .HasForeignKey(k => k.PartDetailsId);
```

I have tried .Map and other variants but all create the DB constraint.

How can I prevent EF from creating the DB FK constraint using the fluent API?

I understand this may not be the best architectural approach but I'm stuck with it.  If I can't find a solution to do this with the Fluent API I will manually drop the constraint in a migration script or drop and re-add the constraint during the purge job.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql

Answer (score 0):

You could manually drop the constraint in a migration script using `Sql("DROP CONSTRAINT...")`.

But a better architectural approach would be to drop and re-add the constraint during the purge job. 
It sounds like the purge job is where the problem really lies. Constraints are very important.