# How to set column NOT NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
MyTable{
      Id int not null;
      Name varchar not null;
      TypeId int null;
}
```

Now i want to make my `TypeId` column is `not null`.
First fill it with data:

```
update [dbo].[MyTable]
set [dbo].[MyTable].[TypeId] = 1
where [dbo].[MyTable].[TypeId] is null
```

And set not null:

```
go
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [TypeId] BIT NOT NULL;
```

But get an error:

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'FK_MyTable_ObjTypes' is dependent on column 'TypeId'.

Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN TypeId failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

What to do in this case? I cant use after table if column is FK?

I tried disable constreints:

```
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_ObjTypes];
go
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [TypeId] BIT NOT NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_ObjTypes];
```

But get same error.

Drop and recreate constrains help me. This is my query:

```
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_ObjTypes];
go
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [TypeId] INT NOT NULL;
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_ObjTypes] FOREIGN KEY ([TypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ObjTypes] ([Id]);
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_ObjTypes];
```

Comment: It looks like you have to drop FK_MyTable_ObjTypes first, then you have to alter column and then you have to recreate FK_MyTable_ObjTypes. I think, it's not because of NULL, it's due to you are changing column type from INT to BIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Foreign Key `FK_MyTable_ObjTypes` references the `TypeId` column, so changing the column would invalidate the constraints of the FK.

You will need to remove the FK first (script it as a `CREATE` so you can see what the existing definition is). Then `ALTER` your column, before recreating the FK using the newly modified column.

Comment: Droping and recreating helps me. Thanks. Im add a query text int question.

Answer (score 3):

Yo can disable the FK 'FK_MyTable_ObjTypes', alter the column and enable again the FK:

[How can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql)