# Deleting and restoring foreign key values in SQL Server database table

Tags: sql-server

I am working with loading XML files contents into a table in a SQL Server database, for which I wanted to delete the contents of a table `dbo.Accounting` in the SQL Server database, which has `APC_PK_ID` as its primary key, and then load back its contents from the xml file.

But there was this message that showed up saying:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__Inventori__Accou__29CC2871". The conflict occurred in database "PAModel", table "dbo.Inventories", column 'APC_PK_ID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

So now I figured out that I had to delete the column contents of `APC_PK_ID` from `dbo.Inventories` table separately.

But the point of concern for me is, is it possible to restore back the contents of `APC_PK_ID` in the `dbo.Inventories` table, as it was before deletion?

Will there be any data loss or problem in loading the data back, if there happens to be a method?

Thank you for checking into the question.

Comment: Either you have to drop the foreign key constraint, or set all the values in the FK column to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to remove (`DROP`) the foreign key constraint, you can disabled it instead, using `NOCHECK CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Inventories NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK__Inventori__Accou__29CC2871
```

And after the changes, to enable again:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Inventories WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT FK__Inventori__Accou__29CC2871
```

Off course, if there's any inconsistent data, you won't be able to enable the constraint

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common topic:
[How can foreign key constraints be temporarily disabled using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/how-can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql)

Enabling/Disabling constraints will not result to data loss.
However, you cannot enable them back if you have data inconsistancy.
For instance, child table record refers to a missing record of parent table