# Selecting from table with deleted foreignkeys results in ProgrammingError: 1146, "Table <tablename> doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, orm, foreign-keys, pymysql

**Background**

I'm working with a Mysql database generated from a legacy SQL dump file. Some tables have been deleted from said SQL dump file.

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm using SQLAlchemy and pymysql to select rows, and going by [the official tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#executing-with-an-orm-session):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, MetaData, Table
import pymysql

metadata = MetaData()
db_connection_str = f'mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_password}@localhost/{db_name}'
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)
test_table = Table(<table_name>, metadata, autoload_with=db_connection)
```

Works, but not for all tables. For one particular table (which exists in the database), it throws this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table '<missing_table_name>' doesn't exist")
[SQL: SHOW CREATE TABLE `<missing_table_name>`]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

The existing table also contains a `MUL` Key column, with a description that says it points to `<missing_table_name>`. It appears that `<missing_table_name>` was deleted before exporting the SQL dump file.

Is there a workaround that would allow me to select rows from the existing table?

Comment: Delete the foreign key from the sql dump before importing the data to mysql?

Comment: Or, you could create the `missing_table_name`. But it will be hard to create it with the correct (expected) definition).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon [this somewhat-related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49554710/2616120) which led me to wonder if `Table` takes a similar argument that disables foreign key checking. Per the docs, this doesn't throw the error above:

```
test_table = Table('<table_name>', metadata, autoload_with=db_connection,resolve_fks=False)
```

However, I'm not sure it'll allow me to use foreign-key based queries. Will mark this question as answered once that is confirmed.