# Under what circumstances could it ever be possible for a parent table to be missing records referenced by active foreign keys in child tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, referential-integrity

I'm at a total loss here.

I have a SQL Server database with a central, most critical table, with many, *many* child tables that have foreign key relationships to it. The foreign key checking is enabled on all tables. I ran `EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"` just to be sure.

Yet somehow there are records in multiple child tables that have foreign keys referencing 6 records in the parent table that do not exist.

***HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE?***

I ran DBCC CHECKDB to see if maybe there was database corruption and I got:

> CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'xxxxxDev'.
>   DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

What am I missing here? How can this be? I'm "shook".[image]

Comment: Could you check if this query returns any rows: select * from sys.foreign_keys where is_not_trusted = 1

Comment: No rows returned by that query

Comment: It's possible foreign key checking was turned off temporarily during insert/update e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159038/how-can-foreign-key-constraints-be-temporarily-disabled-using-t-sql

Comment: The thought had occurred to me, but if that were the case, shouldn't EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all" fail?

Comment: @Piotr yes - didn't see your comment while I was writing mine...

Comment: Sounds like corruption or engine bug, I would recommend opening a case with Microsoft.

Comment: Can you make a backup of this DB, turn off this constraint and then try to re enable it?

Comment: It's a development DB. I'll drop and re-create the constraint... it completed successfully... *smh*

Comment: Could you check if you have any Row-Level Security enabled for parent table?

Comment: HAHA! Thank you!  I forgot that another developer was experimenting with filter predicates... That's it, I think:

ALTER SECURITY POLICY [dbo].[programAccessPolicy] 
ALTER FILTER PREDICATE [dbo].[programPredicate]([ID]) ON [Mongoose].[Program],
ALTER BLOCK PREDICATE [dbo].[programPredicate]([ID]) ON [Mongoose].[Program]

Comment: How can I find the definition of [dbo].[programPredicate]?

Comment: Found it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reason for this is a Row-Level Security enabled for parent table.
It may be hiding rows from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you "Piotr" (https://stackoverflow.com/users/10542581/piotr) for the answer.

A developer had added a predicate to the security policy for that table (row-level security) that was hiding the rows. He never removed it, and I forgot it was there.

I thought I was going nuts...