# Updating Multiple Observations at the Same Time with a SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I am trying to update multiple tables at the same time in SQL. I have a Products table which includes ProductName and ProductTypeID. I also have another table called ProductCategory which includes the ProductTypeID as the primary key and the full product type name. For example,

```
Products Table
ProductName  ProductTypeID  Price ...
Bananas      FR             0.79  ...
Milk         DR             2.19  ...
...          ...            ...   ...
```

and

```
ProductCategory Table
ProductType  CategoryName
FR           Fruit
DR           Dairy
...          ...
```

In my database, the fruit and vegetable sections are combining categories, so I want "Fruit" to become "Produce" and "FR" to become "PR". However, with the multiple table configuration, I am struggling to find a way to do this. I have been working with a stored procedure since that seems to be the simplest way to accomplish this.

The results would look like the following:

```
Products Table
ProductName  ProductTypeID  Price ...
Bananas      PR             0.79  ...
Milk         DR             2.19  ...
...          ...            ...   ...
```

and

```
ProductCategory Table
ProductType  CategoryName
Produce      PR
DR           Dairy
...          ...
```

Comment: *so I want "Fruit" to become "Produce" and "FR" to become "PR"* Don't understand this - where is "Produce" and "PR", what do you mean. Include the procedure you've got so far. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @DaleK sorry for the ambiguity, I provided some desired results now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an SP to accomplish this.

Try temporarily disabling the FK constraint via `ALTER TABLE Products NOCHECK CONSTRAINTS ALL`

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/159064/206413
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-check-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements?view=sql-server-ver15