# Delete all table entries in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-delete

Is it possible delete all entries in a table and reset the autonumber count?
I have tried:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
DELETE FROM a_test
End Sub
```

But it I get an error "Expected end of statement". I am using Access 2010.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951780/clear-all-the-rows-in-a-table-resetting-the-identity-specification-back-to-zero

Comment: See **[here](http://allenbrowne.com/func-ADOX.html#ResetSeed)**. The key is:

`strSql = "ALTER TABLE [" & strTable & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & strAutoNum & "] COUNTER(" & lngNext & ", 1);"`

Alternatively, just drop and recreate the table.

Comment: Anyway, I think you are trying to execute a macro (Private Sub). You need to create a statement and execute it inside your Sub block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is not to worry so much about reseeding the autonumber.  Let Access maintain it's uniqueness.  If you need to reset it, look at the comments others have posted.

In regards to fixing your actual error, you're not actually running anything above.  If you want to run a SQL statement, you can use `CurrentDb.Execute` or something like this:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM a_test"
End Sub
```

Comment: ha, wow, well thank you, i never did sql so i didnt know. i feel dumb now

Comment: @BigApeWhat -- no worries, that's how we learn :)  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting all rows, you can drop the table and create it again. It's not very effective nor clean, but it'll reset the autonumber count.

Comment: will my relations stay the same. cause my program is like a resturant and when the day is finished i want to clear all the records and reset the autonumber.

Comment: Not sure of that, sorry. You'll have to test.